# List numbers within given ranges

Tags: code-golf, number, sequence

### Goal:

Your goal is to print out numbers within a given range (*Also including given values*).

### Input Format:

The input will look like:
`(int-int, int-int, ...)`

`...` meaning the user can add as many `int-int` as they'd like.

### Other Info:

- You will only have to handle *non-negative* integer numbers.
- The first integer in `int-int` will always be smaller, or the same, then the next integer in `int-int`
- The input will *always have at least two* `int-int`
- Each `int-int` will followed by a comma and a space, except for the last one.
- This is [code-golf](/questions/tagged/code-golf) meaning the shortest answer wins!

### Examples / Test Cases:

- Example 1:
- Input:
  `(10-13, 11-15, 0-3)`
- Output:
  `10 11 12 13 11 12 13 14 15 0 1 2 3`
- Example 2:
- Input:
  `(1-5, 1-15)`
- Output:
  `1 2 3 4 5 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 11 12 13 14 15`
- Example 3:
- Input:
  `(1-2, 1-3, 1-3, 1-2)`
- Output:
  `1 2 1 2 3 1 2 3 1 2`
- Example 4:
- Input:
  `(4-6, 0-1, 9-9)`
- Output:
  `4 5 6 0 1 9`

Comment: Will the input have all the `(` and the `, ` or can we take an array of `n-n` for the input?

Comment: @Downgoat It will have all the other `(`, `, `, `)` too.

Comment: Will the first integer always be less than the second or can it be reversed and still be valid? e.g. `11-10` would give `11 10`

I'd recommend adding a test case for that and for when the integers are the same (e.g. `10-10` -- though I'd imagine this would give `10`)

Comment: @Cole Great question(s), yes the first integer will always be smaller and in the case of the numbers being the same it should just print that number (`8-8` => `8`).

Comment: Unfortunate that this was closed. It isn't a complete duplicate, as the other one requires comma-separated output. I have a cute answer (valid?) in ngn/apl: Instead of a program/function to do the work, I redefine *minus* to give the desired output: `-←{(⊃~⍨/⍳¨⍺,1+↑⍵),1↓⍵}`. Now `(10-13, 11-15, 0-3)` evaluates to `10 11 12 13 11 12 13 14 15 0 1 2 3`!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## CJam, 19

```
qS/{'.,Ser~),>~}%S*
```

Martin Büttner killed 2 bytes again, thanks :)
[Try it online](http://cjam.aditsu.net/#code=qS%2F%7B'.%2CSer~)%2C%3E~%7D%25S*&input=(4-6%2C%200-1%2C%209-9))

**Explanation:**

```
q       read input
S/      split by space
{…}%    transform each string (containing a pair of numbers and some other chars)
  '.,   enumerate all characters smaller than '.'
  Ser   replace them all with a space in the string
  ~     evaluate the resulting string, pushing the 2 numbers on the stack
         let's call them A and B
  ),    create an array [0 1 … B]
  >     slice it from A: [A … B]
  ~     dump it onto the stack
S*      join the resulting array with spaces
```

Answer (score 3):

### [Minkolang 0.13](https://github.com/elendiastarman/Minkolang), 12 bytes

```
nd1+?.n~Lr$N
```

[Try it here.](http://play.starmaninnovations.com/minkolang/?code=nd1%2B%3F%2En%7ELr%24N&input=%2810-13%2C%2011-15%2C%200-3%29)

#### Explanation

```
n      Take number from input (-1 if input is devoid of numbers)
d1+    Duplicate and add 1
?.     If this is 0, stop.
n~     Get number from input and negate it (because of the '-')
L      Pops b,a and pushes a,a+1,a+2,...,b-1,b
r      Reverses list
$N     Outputs whole stack as numbers
```

Answer (score 2):

## Julia, 75 bytes

```julia
s->print((j=join)(map(i->j(i," "),eval(parse(replace(s,"-",":"))))," "))
```

This is an anonymous function that accepts a string and prints to STDOUT. To call it, give it a name, e.g. `f=s->...`.

Ungolfed:

```julia
function f(s::AbstractString)
    # Replace dashes with colons in the input
    c = replace(s, "-", ":")

    # Parse as a tuple of UnitRange objects
    r = eval(parse(c))

    # Join each range with spaces
    m = map(i -> join(i, " "), r)

    # Join into one string and print
    print(join(m, " "))
end
```

Answer (score 2):

### Javascript (ES 2015), <s>86</s> 83 bytes

```
f=r=>{z="";r.replace(/(?:(\d+).(\d+))/g,(m,n,x)=>{do{z+=n+" "}while(n++<x)});alert(z)}
```

Live Demo: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/BoeEGO?editors=001

---

**Edit 1**: saved 3 bytes changing the body of the inner function into `for(;n<=x;)z+=n+++" "` (and I feel good when the horizontal scrollbar of my snippet at last disappears :) )

```
f=r=>{z="";r.replace(/(?:(\d+).(\d+))/g,(m,n,x)=>{for(;n<=x;)z+=n+++" "});alert(z)}
```

---

Ungolfed

```
f=r=>{                                       // define a function with 'r' arg

  z="";                                      // initialize a variable to collect 
                                             // the output

  r.replace(/(?:(\d+).(\d+))/g,(m,n,x)=>{    // for each range     
                                             // where (m=range, n=min, x=max)
    for(; n<=x; ) {                          // until min <= max
      z += n++ + " "                         // add to z the value and a space
    }                       
  });

  alert(z)                                   // alert the output
}
```

---

```
f("(10-13, 11-15, 0-3, 9-9)");  // Output: 10 11 12 13 11 12 13 14 15 0 1 2 3 9
```

Answer (score 1):

## TeaScript, 18 + 1 = 19 bytes <s>20</s>

<sup>+1 byte for "Inputs are arrays / lists?"  checkbox</sup>

Such abuse...

```
xße`r(${ls`-`}¬)`)
```

I've never abused JavaScript's casting more in my life.

[Try it online](http://vihanserver.tk/p/TeaScript/#?code=%22x%C3%9Fe(%60r($%7Bls%60-%60%7D%C2%AC)%60%C2%A9%22&inputs=%5B%22(1-2,%201-3,%201-3,%201-2)%22,%22%22%5D&opts=%7B%22int%22:false,%22ar%22:true,%22debug%22:false,%22chars%22:false,%22html%22:false%7D)

### Ungolfed && Explanation

My favorite part is JavaScript arrays when cast to a string have commas auto-inserted. We abuse this so the array elements are inserted as numbers *and* as separate arguments. So `1-2`, would become `['1','2']` but when string casted `1,2` and this can be put directly in a function.

```
xm(#e`r(${ls`-`}+1)`)

                        // The checkbox makes the input like ['1-2','3-4']
xm(#                )   // Loop through input
    e`             `    // Eval string...
      r(        +1)     // range function...
        ${ls`-`}        // Convert range -> args
                        // See above for more details
```

Answer (score 1):

### Python 2, 125 bytes

```py
import re
print' '.join(map(lambda x:' '.join([str(y)for y in x]),eval(re.sub('(\d+)-(\d+)',r'range(\1,\2+1)',raw_input()))))
```

[Try it online](http://ideone.com/fork/YnDE68)

I'm certain this could be golfed more...

Answer (score 1):

### CJam, 41 bytes (too long!)

Definitely can be golfed, but its a start. Test it online [here](http://cjam.aditsu.net/#code=l'(%2Fe_')%2Fe_'%2C%2F%7B%5B'-'%20er~%5D2%2C.%2B%3A%2CW%25%3A-%7D%25e_'%20*&input=(1-2%2C2-4)).

```
l'(/e_')/e_',/{['-' er~]2,.+:,W%:-}%e_' *

l                                           e# Take string input
 '(/e_                                      e# Remove '( characters
      ')/e_                                 e# Remove ') characters
           ',/                              e# Split on commas
              {                   }%        e# Map over array...
               ['-' er~]                       e# Convert A-B to [A B]
                        2,.+                   e# Convert [A B] to [A B+1]
                            :,W%               e# Convert [A B+1] to [[0,1,2, ... B][0, 1, 2, ... A]]
                                :-             e# Remove element 1 of the previous array from element 2
                                    e_' *   e# Format nicely
                                            e# CJam prints stack after execution
```

Comment: A few tips: 1. To remove '(', do `'(-`; even better in this case: `1>`; similarly, `')-` or `W<` 2. To convert A-B to [A B], do `'-/:~` 3. To convert [A B] to [A … B], do `~),>` 4. Instead of `e_` after the loop, you can do `~` at the end of the loop 5. Use `S` instead of `' `

Answer (score 1):

## [O](https://github.com/phase/o), <s>75</s> 74 bytes

```
I'(-')-", "/]{[[n'-/]{n#}d[$,.$.0=0={.@=0={;.@=0=}w;}{;;}?r]]{n{noTo}d}d}d
```

This makes logical sense to anyone who built the language (i.e. me). The logic behind this is intense and I'm just happy that I got it working.

[Try it online](http://o-lang.herokuapp.com/link/W2knKC0nKS0iLCUyMCIvXXtbW24nLS9de24jfWRbJCwuJC4wPTA9ey5APTA9ezsuQD0wPX13O317Ozt9P3JdXXtue25vVG99ZH1kfWQ=/KDEwLTEzLCUyMDExLTE1LCUyMDAtMyk=) or [RUN EVERY TEST CASE AT THE SAME TIME](http://o-lang.herokuapp.com/link/W2lpaWlde1tuJygtJyktIiwlMjAiL117W1tuJy0vXXtuI31kWyQsLiQuMD0wPXsuQD0wPXs7LkA9MD19dzt9ezs7fT9yXV17bntub1RvfWR9ZH1kVXB9ZA==/KDEwLTEzLCUyMDExLTE1LCUyMDAtMykKKDEtNSwlMjAxLTE1KQooMS0yLCUyMDEtMywlMjAxLTMsJTIwMS0yKQooNC02LCUyMDAtMSwlMjA5LTkp)

Explanation:

```
I'(-')-", "/]    Format inputs into array
{                 Iterate over each input range
 [[n'-/]{n#}d     Split ranges into sets of numbers
 [$,              Get the second number and get a range from 0 to it
 .$.0=0=          Is the first number 0?
 {.@=0={;.@=0=}w;} True: Remove any unneeded numbers
 {;;}?             False: Pop some random stuff that shouldn't have been on there to begin with
 r]]              Reverse the range and close some array stuff or whatever
 {n{noTo}d}d}     Format output
}d
```

Comment: No idea what any of it does but good job.

Comment: Maybe would be better to specify the version too. As I see, your answers work only with the new C interpreter, but until you document it I will keep posting answers which work only with the old Java interpreter (like the [99 bottles of beer](http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/64466) one).

Comment: @manatwork That answer actually works on the IDE. The C interpreter has most of the same features as the old one, and most old programs will work unless they do crazy stuff.

Comment: Hmm… Indeed. Maybe I tested only an older version of the code. But on thing is sure, was not the only time we didn't understood each other with the online interpreter.

Answer (score 1):

### Python 3, 76 bytes

```python
l=eval(input().replace(*'-,'))
while l:a,b,*l=l;print(*range(a,b+1),end=' ')
```

The input is evaluated as a tuple by replacing each `-` with `,`

```python
(10-13, 11-15, 0-3) --> (10,13, 11,15, 0,3)
```

Then, the first two elements of the list are repeatedly lopped off and the numbers between them are printed.

Saved 2 bytes thanks to xsot.

Comment: `'-',','` can be shortened to `*'-,'`.

Comment: @xsot Thanks. I wonder if there's something to be done with `replace('-',',1+')` to get the ranges right...

Answer (score 1):

## Mathematica, 80 bytes

```
Join@@BlockMap[Range@@FromDigits/@#&,StringCases[#,DigitCharacter..],2]~Row~" "&
```