# Easier communication means faster coding means fewer coders means …

Tags: code-golf, string, kolmogorov-complexity, animation

My father who [was a really good APLer](https://youtu.be/pL8OQIR5cB4?t=3m16s) and taught me all the basics of APL (and much more), passed away on this day, five years ago. In preparation for [50 Years of APL](http://www.dyalog.com/50-years-of-apl.htm), I found [this patent letter](https://tidsskrift.dk/plugins/generic/pdfJsViewer/pdf.js/web/viewer.html?file=https%3A%2F%2Ftidsskrift.dk%2Fregistreringstidende-varemaerker%2Farticle%2Fdownload%2F95152%2F143241%2F#page=8) (translated for the convenience of those who do not read Danish) for a handwritten logo. It explains a major reason for APL never gaining a large user base – a reason which of course applies to all of this community's amazing golfing languages too:

---

A 3497/77                           Req. 29<sup>th</sup> Aug. 1977 at 13

[image: EASIER COMMUNICATION MEANS FASTER CODING MEANS FEWER CODERS MEANS …]

**Henri Brudzewsky,** engineering consultancy company, **Mindevej 28, Søborg,**

**class 9**, including computers, especially APL coded computers,
**class 42:** IT service agency company, especially during use of APL coded computers.

---

## Task

**Produce infinitely repeating output of the text `EASIER COMMUNICATION MEANS FASTER CODING MEANS FEWER CODERS MEANS`  with no newlines.** You may begin the text with `EASIER` or `FASTER` or `FEWER`.

Comment: I misinterpreted your challenge and what I did was https://i.imgur.com/qKnTj3q.png !

Comment: @sergiol Almost valid [over here](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/119469/43319).

Comment: Link to patent letter is dead.

Comment: @pppery Thanks. Updated.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

## [05AB1E](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E), 25 bytes

```
[‘Ã¦ƒËRSˆ¾¥ƒŽÁˆ¾¡ŸÂïˆ¾ ‘?
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/nexus/05ab1e#@x/9qGHG4eZDy45NOtwdFHy67dC@Q0uPTTq693AjmL3w6I7DTYfXg9gKQJX2//8DAA)

Explanation:

```
[‘Ã¦ƒËRSˆ¾¥ƒŽÁˆ¾¡ŸÂïˆ¾ ‘?
[                         Start infinite loop
 ‘Ã¦ƒËRSˆ¾¥ƒŽÁˆ¾¡ŸÂïˆ¾ ‘   Push the compressed string in uppercase, starting from FEWER, with a trailing space
                        ?  Print without trailing newline
```

Comment: Honestly, I don't understand why Python solutions get explanations and this one doesn't. What in the world is happening here?

Comment: @nluigi black magic

Comment: It's physically impossible to know what is going on here if you don't know the language, would you mind giving an explanation please.

Comment: @nluigi Because Python users normally go for readability in everyday life. 05AB1E is focused on code golf.

Comment: @nluigi The `[` means 'start of infinite loop', the `‘Ã¦ƒËRSˆ¾¥ƒŽÁˆ¾¡ŸÂïˆ¾ ‘` is a compressed version of `EASIER COMMUNICATION MEANS FASTER CODING MEANS FEWER CODERS MEANS `, and `?` means print without newline.

Comment: @nluigi Explanation added, although what Okx said (I didn't have time to add an explanation yesterday) and not very impressive.

Comment: But how does string compression work in 05AB1E? I couldn't find an explanation anywhere

Comment: @Leo That's greatly under-explained. First, you go to [this](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E/blob/master/docs/info.txt) file. To the right of some of the extended characters, you can see a number. If it's one-digit, pad with a leading zero. Two such chars form a 4-digit number with possible leading zeroes. Then, this number is used as an zero-based index to [this](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E/blob/master/lib/dictionary.py) dictionary. The behavior of each word then depends on the quotes, which you can find on the first file I linked by searching for `compressed`.

Answer (score 41):

### SVG(HTML5), 336 bytes

```html
<svg width=500 height=500><defs><path id=p d=M49,250a201,201,0,0,1,402,0a201,201,0,0,1,-402,0></defs><text font-size="32"><textPath xlink:href=#p>EASIER COMMUNICATION MEANS FASTER CODING MEANS FEWER CODERS MEANS</textPath><animateTransform attributeName=transform type=rotate from=360,250,250 to=0,250,250 dur=9s repeatCount=indefinite>
```

Edit: Some people have found that the font doesn't quite fit for them so here is a version that allows you a few pixels of adjustment:

```html
<p><input type=number value=0 min=0 max=9 oninput=p.setAttribute('d','M250,250m20_,0a20_,20_,0,1,1,-20_,-20_a20_,20_,0,1,1,-20_,20_a20_,20_,0,1,1,20_,20_a20_,20_,0,1,1,20_,-20_'.replace(/_/g,this.value))></p>
<svg width=500 height=500><defs><path id=p d=M250,250m200,0a200,200,0,1,1,-200,-200a200,200,0,1,1,-200,200a200,200,0,1,1,200,200a200,200,0,1,1,200,-200></defs><text font-size="32"><textPath xlink:href=#p>EASIER COMMUNICATION MEANS FASTER CODING MEANS FEWER CODERS MEANS</textPath><animateTransform attributeName=transform type=rotate from=360,250,250 to=0,250,250 dur=9s repeatCount=indefinite>
```

Comment: This is beautiful, but can you make it inside out (top of letters facing out from the circle) and all uppercase?

Comment: @Adám How's this? I've had to tweak the dimensions slightly but it's the same byte count.

Comment: Stunning. It actually qualifies, as running your code snippet displays the text scrolling in a half-circle, so it really is infinitely repeating the required text. I was actually thinking of posting a challenge for a circular output too.

Comment: @Adám If you click "Full page" then you'll see the bottom half of the circle too...

Comment: @Adám, you should; that's what I thought this challenge was going to be when I first read it.

Comment: @Shaggy [Here you go](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/119469/easier-communication-means-circular-edition).

Comment: @Adám Now I'm conflicted. I've got 11 votes here...

Comment: Leave it. Your submission here *is* valid, and it is the shortest (only) SVG submission here. But head over there now…

Comment: There's a space missing in "MEANSEASIER", which is present between other words.

Comment: @ShreevatsaR I guess you must be using a slightly different font to me, I don't know of an easy way to fix that, except possibly through the use of a textbox to allow the output to be adjusted on a pixel-by-pixel basis.

Comment: @Neil My browser says that the font being used is Times. Note that this missing space is at the boundary between where the textpath ends (`…MEANS`) and where it begins (`EASIER…`). I tried simply inserting a space into the textpath but it didn't work. I get slightly better results if I change the textpath to move the E from the beginning to the end (that is: `ASIER COMMUNICATION`…`CODERS MEANS E`): then the E and A run into each other slightly.

Comment: Anyone try this with the font in the original picture

Comment: @ShreevatsaR I've added a second version which includes a textbox for making small adjustments, maybe that helps.

Answer (score 13):

## PHP, 76 Bytes

```php
for(;;)echo strtr(EASI0MMUNICATION1FAST0DING1FEW0DERS1,["ER CO"," MEANS "]);
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/nexus/php#s7EvyCjgSi0qyi@KL0otyC8qycxL16hzjffzD/F0dtW0/p@WX6Rhba2ZmpyRr1BcUlRSpOHqGOxp4Osb6ufp7Bji6e9n6OYYHGLg4unnbujmGm7g4hoUbKgTreQapODsr6SjpODr6ugXrKAUCzTsPwA)

Comment: Only in PHP....

Comment: @immibis What do you mean?

Comment: I mean you managed to demonstrate at least 3 PHP "design quirks" in one line of code. This line of code is an illustration of why PHP is considered harmful.

Comment: @immibis It is only harmful if you not know what you are doing. And with PHP 7 you can do it in a better way as before.

Comment: @immibis "mimimi don't like php" Thought we were past that point for like a decade. :-)

Comment: @immibis Could you name those 'design quirks'? I need PHP for a certain project and I would definitely like to know what to avoid if I don't know when I'm doing.

Comment: @Arc676 First, a name without a dollar sign is assumed to be a constant. Second, an undefined constant is assumed to be itself as a string. So in this code `EASI0MMUNICATION1FAST0DING1FEW0DERS1` is treated as the string `"EASI0MMUNICATION1FAST0DING1FEW0DERS1"`. Third, `strtr` expects an associative array (a "map" or "dictionary" in other languages), but this code passed in a regular array, so it treats the regular array as an associative array with keys 0 and 1. Finally, those integers 0 and 1 get treated as strings `"0"` and `"1"` because, you guessed it, the function needs strings.

Answer (score 12):

## Vim 69 bytes

```
qqAFEWER CODERS MEANS EASIER COMMUNICATION M<C-n> FASTER CODING M<C-n> <esc>@qq@q
```

Comment: I just *love* it when a straightforward Vim command sequence makes for a decent code golf solution. :-D

Answer (score 6):

## [Python 2](https://docs.python.org/2/), <s>82</s> 81 bytes

*-1 byte thanks to Leaky Nun.*

I'm probably doing something wrong but it's really late so meh. Note the trailing comma.

```python
while 1:print'FEWER CODERS MEANS EASIER COMMUNICATION MEANS FASTER CODING MEANS',
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/nexus/python2#@1@ekZmTqmBoVVCUmVei7uYa7hqk4Ozv4hoUrODr6ugXrODqGOwJFvP1DfXzdHYM8fT3g0q5OQaHQJR7@rlDxNR1/v//mpevm5yYnJEKAA)

### Another solution, 85 bytes

I can probably golf this further.

```python
while 1:print'%sER CO%s MEANS'*3%('FEW','DERS',' EASI','MMUNICATION',' FAST','DING'),
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/nexus/python2#@1@ekZmTqmBoVVCUmVeirlrsGqTg7K9arODr6ugXrK5lrKqh7uYarq6j7uIaFAykFFwdgz2BtK9vqJ@ns2OIp78fSNTNMTgEpMjTz11dU@f/fwA)

Comment: You can delete the second space.

Comment: @LeakyNun How did I miss that? o0 Thanks!

Comment: In the second one, you can move the spaces into the format string.

Comment: @wizzwizz4 Leading whitespace is disallowed.

Comment: @totallyhuman Currently, you have a bug where it will output "FEWER CODERS MEANSEASIER COMMUNICATION MEANSFASTER CODING MEANSFEWER...". If you change the format string to `'%sER CO%s MEANS '` and remove the spaces from the format items, it'll be golfier and work properly.

Comment: @wizzwizz4 Erm... I don't see this bug. Are you sure you're including the trailing comma?

Comment: @totallyhuman No, I wasn't. Your code works fine. However, making that change would save one more byte than I previously thought.

Answer (score 6):

### HTML, 122 bytes.

Sorry, can't help myself.

```html
<marquee style="width:5em;word-spacing:5em;">EASIER COMMUNICATION MEANS FASTER CODING MEANS FEWER CODERS MEANS </marquee>
```

Comment: why the huge word spacing?

Comment: @Adám Because a marquee always leaves that amount of width between iterations (i.e. its own width). And I couldn't find a way to collapse that, so I had to improvise and put the same amount of space between each word as well.

Comment: Can't you remove the end tag?

Comment: @NoOneIsHere How would that help? Or did you mean it would golf it down by 10 bytes? I'm not sure I want to do that; the end tag is not actually optional.

Comment: @MrLister I meant golf it down. I thought single-tag HTML documents didn't need the end tag.

Answer (score 5):

## [Jelly](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly), <s>33</s> 29 bytes

4 bytes thanks to Erik the Outgolfer.

```
“©%5ÐƬwȮh¬Þ6.⁷ḷḊḥṫɠlḶṀġß»Œu⁶¢
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/nexus/jelly#AT4Awf//4oCcwqklNcOQxqx3yK5owqzDnjYu4oG34bi34biK4bil4bmryaBs4bi24bmAxKHDn8K7xZJ14oG2wqL//w)

Comment: 1) You can use a better compressed string: `“©%5ÐƬwȮh¬Þ6.⁷ḷḊḥṫɠlḶṀġß»` (still need to use `Œu` and `;⁶`) 2) You can use `ß` instead of `1¿`.

Answer (score 5):

## [Brachylog](https://github.com/JCumin/Brachylog), 70 bytes

```
"FEWER CODERS MEANS EASIER COMMUNICATION MEANS FASTER CODING MEANS "w↰
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/nexus/brachylog2#@6/k5hruGqTg7O/iGhSs4Ovq6Bes4OoY7AkW8/UN9fN0dgzx9PeDSrk5BodAlHv6uUPFlMoftW34/x8A)

### How it works

```
"..."w↰
"..."     generate the string "..."
     w    print to STDOUT without trailing newline
      ↰   do the whole thing all over again
```

Answer (score 4):

## HTML/CSS (firefox only), <s>179</s> <s>177</s> <s>183</s> <s>176</s> 173 bytes

```
<b id=a>EASIER COMMUNICATION MEANS FASTER CODING MEANS FEWER CODERS MEANS </b>E<a><style>*{margin:0;}a{position:fixed;left:0;right:0;height:1em;background:-moz-element(#a)}
```

Certianly nowhere near the lowest scores, I just thought it would be fun to get infinite repitition in HTML/CSS, without any JS involved :)

### Changelog:

- Removed quotes around id attribute
- added "round" background-repeat to stretch the text so it wraps correctly
- changed to single-line output
- replace `width:100%` style with `right:0` to save 3 bytes

Comment: Nice try, but that starts over on every line. OP: **with no newlines.**

Comment: Any of the answers that print to a terminal will wrap at the end of the row. Try zooming out; you'll see it continues on forever horizontally as well, it's just "hidden" by the browser window.

Comment: Also, I wasted a few bytes having the repeating image "round off" so that it wraps more convincingly, hope that helps

Comment: Wrapping is fine, but yours doesn't. It could be seen as "printing" infinitely many infinite lines. Just restrict the background to a single line.

Comment: Since my original submission I edited it to pretend to "wrap"; it stretches the image the smallest amount necessary so that the last repitition of the sentence on each line ends at the edge of the screen. If this is not acceptable I can throw in a `repeat no-repeat` but that'll be costly :(

Comment: Yeah, well, you're not winning against other languages anyway…

Comment: doesn't mean i'm not aiming to do the best I can given the constraints of the language!

Comment: Right, but you've got to stick to the OP specs. Won't it save you to avoid the rounding?

Comment: yes. i thought i would have to put `repeat no-repeat` or `; background-repeat: repeat-x`, but figured out how to avoid it. Turns out obeying the spec saves bytes!

Answer (score 3):

## [Python 3](https://docs.python.org/3/), 87 bytes

```python
while 1:print(end="FEWER CODERS MEANS EASIER COMMUNICATION MEANS FASTER CODING MEANS ")
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/nexus/python3#@1@ekZmTqmBoVVCUmVeikZqXYqvk5hruGqTg7O/iGhSs4Ovq6Bes4OoY7AkW8/UN9fN0dgzx9PeDSrk5BodAlHv6uUPFlDT//wcA)

Comment: What does `end=` do?

Comment: @Adám It lets you print without a trailing newline.

Comment: @Adám The default arguments to `print` are `print("",end="\n")`.

Comment: I thought that substituting `ER CO` and `MEANS` (leading+trailing space) would save some bytes, but apparently not.

Answer (score 3):

## [C (gcc)](https://gcc.gnu.org/), 92 bytes

```c
main(){for(;printf("FEWER CODERS MEANS EASIER COMMUNICATION MEANS FASTER CODING MEANS "););}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/nexus/c-gcc#@5@bmJmnoVmdll@kYV1QlJlXkqah5OYa7hqk4Ozv4hoUrODr6ugXrODqGOwJFvP1DfXzdHYM8fT3g0q5OQaHQJR7@rlDxZQ0rTWta///BwA)

Answer (score 3):

## [LOLCODE](http://lolcode.org/), 116 bytes

```
HAI 1
IM IN YR O
VISIBLE "FEWER CODERS MEANS EASIER COMMUNICATION MEANS FASTER CODING MEANS "!
IM OUTTA YR O
KTHXBYE
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/nexus/lolcode#LYzLDYAwDMXunSKwASMECPAETaUmfLr/IEV8rrblujCoC4gEpZIphQOGfhNqJzkl05BGyUZRWI2EDS@LcVcM7Ej6q4nNvxw6/6xtnnHa3fl7r75cfZFabw)

Comment: I'm not familiar with LOLCODE. How does this output forever?

Comment: @Challenger5 `IM IN YR ...` and `IM OUTTA YR ...` form an infinite loop.

Comment: You can remove HAI and KTHXBYE as compilers don't require them. Also, no exclamation at end of VISIBLE.

Comment: @OldBunny2800 What version of LOLCODE are you using? In [this](https://github.com/justinmeza/lolcode-spec/blob/master/v1.2/lolcode-spec-v1.2.md#terminal-based) version, the trailing `!` suppresses the carriage return after printing.

Comment: Oh, I forgot about the no-line-break rule. I didn't realize LOLCODE had a way to do this!

Answer (score 3):

## Ruby, 77 bytes

assigning `" MEANS "` to a variable saved all of 1 byte :-)

```
loop{$><<"EASIER COMMUNICATION#{m=" MEANS "}FASTER CODING#{m}FEWER CODERS"+m}
```

Answer (score 3):

## JavaScript (ES6), <s>90</s> 87 bytes

```
while(1)console.log`EASIER COMMUNICATION MEANS FASTER CODING MEANS FEWER CODERS MEANS `
```

---

### Functioning Alternative, 100 bytes

"Functioning" here meaning "won't crash your browser" (for a while, at least)!

```
setInterval(_=>console.log`EASIER COMMUNICATION MEANS FASTER CODING MEANS FEWER CODERS MEANS `,1)
```

Comment: Your code does not work: `document.write\`EASIER COMMUNICATION${m=" MEANS "}FASTER CODING${m}FEWER CODERS\`+m` is equivalent to `document.write([ 'EASIER COMMUNICATION', 'FASTER CODING', 'FEWER CODERS' ], ' MEANS ', ' MEANS ') + ' MEANS '`, which 1) will convert all arguments to strings and concatenate (printing `EASIER COMMUNICATION,FASTER CODING,FEWER CODERS MEANS MEANS `), and 2) won't include the last `' MEANS '` anyways since it's outside the function call...

Answer (score 2):

## [Befunge](https://github.com/catseye/Befunge-93), 73 bytes

```
" SNAEM GNIDOC RETSAF SNAEM NOITACINUMMOC REISAE SNAEM SREDOC REWEF">:#,_
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/nexus/befunge#@6@kEOzn6Oqr4O7n6eLvrBDkGhLs6AYV8/P3DHF09vQL9fUFS3kGO7pCpYKDXCHKw13dlOyslHXi//8HAA)

Comment: Using Befunge 98, you can replace `">:#,_` with `A"k,` and save two bytes. [Link](https://tio.run/nexus/befunge-98#@6@kEOzn6Oqr4O7n6eLvrBDkGhLs6AYV8/P3DHF09vQL9fUFS3kGO7pCpYKDXCHKw13dHJWydf7/BwA)

Answer (score 2):

## Octave, 86 bytes

```
while fprintf('FEWER CODERS MEANS EASIER COMMUNICATION MEANS FASTER CODING MEANS ')end
```

**Explanation:**

This is fairly self-explanatory. The only real "trick" here is to use `while fprintf`. When `fprintf` is given a return argument, it will return the number of characters printed, and all non-zero numbers are considered `true` in Octave, so the loop condition will always be true.

---

I desperately tried to make the more interesting approach shorter, but it turned out to be 9 bytes longer, unfortunately:

```
while fprintf('FEW%sDERS%sEASI%sMMUNICATION%sFAST%sDING%s',{'ER CO',' MEANS '}{'ababab'-96})end
```

This tries to insert the strings `'ER CO'` and `' MEANS'` into the string at the correct locations, using direct indexing where `'ababab'-96` is a shorter version of `[1 2 1 2 1 2]`.

This was a bit shorter (93 bytes), but still longer than the naive approach

```
while fprintf('FEWER CODERS%sEASIER COMMUNICATION%sFASTER CODING%s',{' MEANS '}{[1,1,1]})end
```

And another one (89 bytes), using Level River St's approach:

```
while fprintf(['FEWER CODERS',s=' MEANS ','EASIER COMMUNIDATION',s,'FASTER CODING',s])end
```

This should work in theory, for one less byte than the original solution, but it fails for some strange reason:

```
while fprintf"FEWER CODERS MEANS EASIER COMMUNICATION MEANS FASTER CODING MEANS "
end
```

This uses the buggy feature that `fprintf('abc def')` is equivalent to `fprintf"abc def"`. The `end` must be on the next line, but it's still one byte shorter since two parentheses are skipped.

And one more for 87:

```
while fprintf('FEWER CODERS%sEASIER COMMUNICATION%sFASTER CODING%s',k=' MEANS ',k,k)end
```

---

Well, don't say I didn't try :)

Comment: You do know that `fprintf` recycles arguments right? Your last version can be 6 bytes less, [Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y08uSSxL/f@/PCMzJ1UhraAoM68kTUPdzTXcNUjB2d/FNShYtdjVMdgTzPX1DfXzdHYM8fT3Uy12cwwOgSjy9HNXLVbXUVfwdXX0C1ZQ10zNS/n/HwA "Octave – Try It Online")

Answer (score 2):

### [Alice](https://github.com/m-ender/alice), 70 bytes

```
" SNAEM "k"SREDOC REWEF"e0j"GNIDOC RETSAF"e0j"NOITACINUMMOC REISAE"d&o
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/nexus/alice#@6@kEOzn6OqroJStFBzk6uLvrBDkGu7qppRqkKXk7ucJEQgJdoSI@Pl7hjg6e/qF@vqCJTyDHV2VUtTy//8HAA)

#### Explanation

Unfortunately, reusing the `MEANS` (with spaces) only saves a single byte over just printing the whole thing in one go. Consequently, extracting the `ER CO` would actually cost a byte (or probably more, because it would be slightly more expensive to extract another section).

```
" SNAEM "                Push the code points of " MEANS " in reverse.
k                        If there is a return address on the return address stack (which
                         there isn't right now), pop it and jump there.
"SREDOC REWEF"           Push the code points of "FEWER CODERS" in reverse.
e0j                      Jump to the beginning of the line, pushing the location of the
                         j to the return address stack. Hence, we push the code points
                         of " MEANS " again, but then the k pops the return address and
                         jumps back here.
"GNIDOC RETSAF"          Push the code points of "FASTER CODING" in reverse.
e0j                      Jump to the beginning of the line again.
"NOITACINUMMOC REISAE"   Push the code points of "EASIER COMMUNICATION" in reverse.
d                        Push the stack depth.
&o                       Print that many bytes from the top of the stack.
                         Afterwards the IP wraps around to the first column and the
                         program starts over.
```

Answer (score 2):

### C#, 102 bytes

```c#
_=>{for(;;)System.Console.Write("EASIER COMMUNICATION{0}FASTER CODING{0}FEWER CODERS{0}"," MEANS ");};
```

Answer (score 2):

## [AWK](https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/gawk.html), 85 bytes

```
BEGIN{for(c=" MEANS ";;)printf"EASIER COMMUNICATION"c"FASTER CODING"c"FEWER CODERS"c}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/nexus/awk#@@/k6u7pV52WX6SRbKuk4Ovq6BesoGRtrVlQlJlXkqbk6hjs6Rqk4Ozv6xvq5@nsGOLp76eUrOTmGBwCFnbx9HMH8V3DIVzXoGCl5Nr//wE)

Apparently I came up with the same shortcut as others. All other substitutions take up too much space. :(

Answer (score 2):

## [Retina](https://github.com/m-ender/retina/wiki/The-Language), <s>64</s> 60 bytes

```
+>(`$
EASI_MMUNICATION@FAST_DING@FEW_DERS@
@
 MEANS 
_
ER CO
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K0otycxLNPz/X9tOI0GFy9Ux2DPe1zfUz9PZMcTT38/BzTE4JN7F08/dwc01PN7FNSjYgcuBS8HX1dEvWIErnss1SMHZ//9/AA)

#### Explanation

The program consists of three grouped replacement stages. The group as a whole is applied repeatedly until the output stops changing (which it never will) and the output is printed after each time (rather than just at the end, because there will be no end)

The first stage adds the string `EASI_MMUNICATION@FAST_DING@FEW_DERS@` at the end of the input. The input starts out empty, but keeps growing.

The second stage replaces each of those `@`s with the string `MEANS` (surrounded by a space on each side).

The third stage replaces the `_`s with the string `ER CO`.

Answer (score 1):

## [Pyth](https://github.com/isaacg1/pyth), 69 bytes

```
Wp"FEWER CODERS MEANS EASIER COMMUNICATION MEANS FASTER CODING MEANS
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/nexus/pyth#@x9eoOTmGu4apODs7@IaFKzg6@roF6zg6hjsCRbz9Q3183R2DPH094NKuTkGh0CUe/q5Q8X@/wcA)

### How it works

```
Wp"...
W       while the following is true: (do nothing)
 p      print the following and return the following
  "...
```

Answer (score 1):

## [Lua](https://www.lua.org), 92 bytes

```lua
while 1 do io.write("FEWER CODERS MEANS EASIER COMMUNICATION MEANS FASTER CODING MEANS ")end
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/nexus/lua#@1@ekZmTqmCokJKvkJmvV16UWZKqoeTmGu4apODs7@IaFKzg6@roF6zg6hjsCRbz9Q3183R2DPH094NKuTkGh0CUe/q5Q8WUNFPzUv7/BwA)

Answer (score 1):

## [Java (OpenJDK 9)](http://openjdk.java.net/projects/jdk9/), 114 bytes

```java
static void f(){while(1>0)System.out.print("FEWER CODERS MEANS EASIER COMMUNICATION MEANS FASTER CODING MEANS ");}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/nexus/java-openjdk9#S85JLC5W8E3MzFOo5lIAgoLSpJzMZIXiksQSIFWWn5mikAuU1QguKcrMS4@OVUgsSi/WhCoGgTQNTWswp/Y/siagcHV5RmZOqoahnYFmcGVxSWquXn5piV4B0JwSDSU313DXIAVnfxfXoGAFX1dHv2AFV8dgT7CYr2@on6ezY4invx9Uys0xOASi3NPPHSqmpGld@5@r9v/XvHzd5MTkjFQA) Stop the execution after a few seconds because it does not know when to stop.

Comment: Submissions have to be full programs or functions.

Comment: @KritixiLithos Can it be an anonymous lambda?

Comment: @totallyhuman Yes. In other languages that's allowed; I don't see why Java _should_ be an exception.

Comment: Why stop execution? Just untick *disable output cache*.

Comment: Can't you do while(1)?

Comment: @OldBunny2800 Nerp. Java is just wonderful like that.

Comment: But you can do `for(;;)`

Comment: @KritixiLithos since Java 9 has REPL, I think whatever evaluates to required expression should be acceptable.

Comment: You can remove `static` as it adds absolutely nothing to the answer.

Answer (score 1):

### C, 86 bytes

```
f(){printf("FEWER CODERS MEANS EASIER COMMUNICATION MEANS FASTER CODING MEANS ");f();}
```

See it [work online](https://tio.run/nexus/c-gcc#@5@moVldUJSZV5KmoeTmGu4apODs7@IaFKzg6@roF6zg6hjsCRbz9Q3183R2DPH094NKuTkGh0CUe/q5Q8WUNK2BBlrX/gcaqJCbmJmnoVCWn5mioMlVzcUJkuGq/f81L183OTE5IxUA).

Comment: This depends upon the compiler doing tail-call optimization, but I guess most do.

Comment: @WayneConrad It is a valid answer without that optimization. Infinite recursion satisfies the requirement: *Produce infinitely repeating output*

Comment: Without tail call optimization, the stack will overflow eventually.  Try compiling it with `gcc` (use default options, so no tail call optimization), and when you run it, redirect output to /dev/null in order to speed up the process.  It'll seg fault.  With the '-O2' option, which enables tail call optimization, it runs forever as intended.

Comment: @WayneConrad Infinite recursion is conceptually, infinite. The question doesn't constrain to a practical definition of infinite. By common consensus, infinite recursion is infinitely repeating, in other words, no logic within the program will stop it..

Comment: I am not declaring that your solution is invalid.  All I meant to point out is that, in order to execute properly, a little cooperation is needed from the compiler.

Comment: @WayneConrad Not necessarily. Enough memory will do just as well.

Comment: Can shave off a byte: `f(){f(printf("FEWER CODERS MEANS EASIER COMMUNICATION MEANS FASTER CODING MEANS "));}`

Answer (score 1):

## [bc](https://www.gnu.org/software/bc/manual/html_mono/bc.html), 76 bytes

```
while(1)"EASIER COMMUNICATION MEANS FASTER CODING MEANS FEWER CODERS MEANS "
```

Answer (score 1):

## [MATL](https://github.com/lmendo/MATL), 68 bytes

```
`'EASIER COMMUNICATION*FASTER CODING*FEWER CODERS*'42' MEANS 'Zt&YDT
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/nexus/matl#@5@g7uoY7OkapODs7@sb6ufp7Bji6e@n5eYYHAIWdPH0c9dycw2HcFyDgrXUTYzUFXxdHf2CFdSjStQiXUL@/wcA)

#### Explanation

```
`                                                     % Do...while
  'EASIER COMMUNICATION*FASTER CODING*FEWER CODERS*'  %   Push this string
  42                                                  %   Push 42 (ASCII for '*')
  ' MEANS '                                           %   Push this string  
  Zt                                                  %   String replacement
  &YD                                                 %   printf to STDOUT
  T                                                   %   Push true as loop condition
                                                      % End (implicit)
```

Answer (score 1):

## [Perl 6](https://perl6.org),  <s>81 80</s>  79 bytes

```perl6
print ('EASIER COMMUNICATION','FASTER CODING','FEWER CODERS'X'MEANS'),' 'for ^Inf
```

[Try it](https://tio.run/nexus/perl6#Ky1OVSgz00u2/l9QlJlXoqCh7uoY7OkapODs7@sb6ufp7Bji6e@nrqPu5hgcAhZ28fRzB/FdwyFc16Bg9Qh1X1dHv2B1TR11BfW0/CKFOM@8tP//AQ)

```perl6
loop {print ('EASIER COMMUNICATION','FASTER CODING','FEWER CODERS'X'MEANS'),' '}
```

[Try it](https://tio.run/nexus/perl6#Ky1OVSgz00u2/p@Tn1@gUF1QlJlXoqCh7uoY7OkapODs7@sb6ufp7Bji6e@nrqPu5hgcAhZ28fRzB/FdwyFc16Bg9Qh1X1dHv2B1TR11BfXa//8B)

```perl6
loop {print [~] 'EASIER COMMUNICATION','FASTER CODING','FEWER CODERS'X'MEANS '}
```

[Try it](https://tio.run/nexus/perl6#Ky1OVSgz00u2/p@Tn1@gUF1QlJlXohBdF6ug7uoY7OkapODs7@sb6ufp7Bji6e@nrqPu5hgcAhZ28fRzB/FdwyFc16Bg9Qh1X1dHv2AF9dr//wE)

Answer (score 1):

## Axiom, <s>92</s> 89 bytes

```
repeat fortranLiteral"EASIER COMMUNICATION MEANS FASTER CODING MEANS FEWER CODERS MEANS "
```

insert in one line to Axiom window. Possible there is one function shorter  than "fortranLiteral" that not write "\n"

Answer (score 1):

## [Braingolf](https://esolangs.org/wiki/Braingolf), 77 bytes

```
"FEWER CODERS MEANS EASIER COMMUNICATION MEANS FASTER CODING MEANS "[!&@<1+>]
```

Answer (score 1):

## [Blank](https://esolangs.org/wiki/Blank), 267 bytes

```
[70][69][87][69][82][32][67][79][68][69][82][83][32][77][69][65][78][83][32][69][65][83][73][69][82][32][67][79][77][77][85][78][73][67][65][84][73][79][78][32][77][69][65][78][83][32][70][65][83][84][69][82][32][67][79][68][73][78][71][32][77][69][65][78][83][32]{p}
```

Pushes `FEWER CODERS MEANS EASIER COMMUNICATION MEANS FASTER CODING MEANS` to the stack, then prints it. Never terminates as no `{@}`

Also fun fact, I used the following [Braingolf](https://esolangs.org/wiki/Braingolf) script to generate this code

```
"FEWER CODERS MEANS EASIER COMMUNICATION MEANS FASTER CODING MEANS "l>[<$_<91+2^9-@_ 91+2^7-@l>]"{p}"@3
```

Answer (score 1):

## [PowerShell](https://github.com/TryItOnline/TioSetup/wiki/Powershell), <strike>100</strike> 97 bytes

```powershell
for(){"EASIER COMMUNICATION","FASTER CODING","FEWER CODERS"|%{Write-Host -NoNewLine "$_ MEANS "}}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/nexus/powershell#@1@ekZmTqmGoWa3k6hjs6Rqk4Ozv6xvq5@nsGOLp76eko@TmGBwCFnbx9HMH8V3DIVzXoGClGtXq8KLMklRdj/ziEgVdv3y/1HKfzLxUBSWVeAVfV0e/YAWl2tr//wE)

---

Older answer:

## [PowerShell](https://github.com/TryItOnline/TioSetup/wiki/Powershell), 100 bytes

```powershell
while(1){"EASIER COMMUNICATION","FASTER CODING","FEWER CODERS"|%{Write-Host -NoNewLine "$_ MEANS "}}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/nexus/powershell#@1@ekZmTqmGoWa3k6hjs6Rqk4Ozv6xvq5@nsGOLp76eko@TmGBwCFnbx9HMH8V3DIVzXoGClGtXq8KLMklRdj/ziEgVdv3y/1HKfzLxUBSWVeAVfV0e/YAWl2tr//wE)

PowerShell is a little tricky for this because most dignified ways of outputting to the console also insert a new line.  `Write-Host` is required because of this.  However, it still demonstrates how pipelining can shorten the coding footprint.

You will need to stop the execution after a short time because it will not return as it is an infinite loop.

Edit:  shaved off 3 bytes by changing a `while` loop to a `for` loop.

Answer (score 1):

## Groovy 79 bytes

```
m=" MEANS";for(;;)print"EASIER COMMUNICATION$m FASTER CODING$m FEWER CODERS$m "
```

Uses groovy's string interpolation.

Answer (score 1):

## [Ly](https://github.com/LyricLy/Ly), 75 bytes

```
1[p"EASIER COMMUNICATION MEANS FASTER CODING MEANS FEWER CODERS MEANS "&o1]
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y6n8/98wukDJ1THY0zVIwdnf1zfUz9PZMcTT30/B19XRL1jBzTE4BCzl4unnDhNzDYcIuQYFQ4WU1PINY///BwA)

Explanation:

```
1[p                                                                      1] # infinitely
   "EASIER COMMUNICATION MEANS FASTER CODING MEANS FEWER CODERS MEANS "&o   # print the string
```

Answer (score 1):

## [C# (.NET Core)](https://www.microsoft.com/net/core/platform), 125 bytes

```cs
class c{static void Main(){for(;;)System.Console.Write("EASIER COMMUNICATION{0}FASTER CODING{0}FEWER CODERS{0}"," MEANS ");}}
```

This is a full program rather than just a function like the other C# answer.

[Test online](https://tio.run/##JchNC8IgGADgv/LiaUJFd0@yLDzoYC52HmYhLAVfC0L87fZ1fB6LWxuTa@2BPtzAvDC7O7Prggi2YF6yt/CM/gJq8aGj5RpTxxjtY8C4ut2cfHYdEdxIMUI/KHXWsueTHHTZ1yM3068PUp@@FvOfYjQfkg0BJbg2QCirtbU3)

Answer (score 1):

### [Keg](https://github.com/JonoCode9374/Keg), 69 bytes

```
{ SNAEM GNIDOC RETSAF SNAEM NOITACINUMMOC REISAE SNAEM SREDOC REWEF(,
```

Explanation:

```
{#                                                                     Infinite loop
  SNAEM GNIDOC RETSAF SNAEM NOITACINUMMOC REISAE SNAEM SREDOC REWEF#   Pushing the string reversed
                                                                   (, #And outputting it reversed
```

[TIO](https://tio.run/##y05N//@/WiHYz9HVV8Hdz9PF31khyDUk2NENKubn7xni6OzpF@rrC5byDHZ0hUoFB7lClIe7umno/P8PAA)

Answer (score 1):

## [Hexadecimal Stacking Pseudo-Assembly Language](https://github.com/ConorOBrien-Foxx/Hexadecimal-Stacking-Pseudo-Assembly-Language), 810 bytes

```
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
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##yyguSMz5/98ADIzA2ATONjVGsE1ckdiGSGxTJLaLCUFzTI1w6DVBYrshsY1xmInDHFNzHOabmdDUjybmOMyxpIEfTXC435CO/nXF4RdL7O5EMd8YR/ggmWmKww0obArCEMWdxvjDASpkCCL@/wcA)

```
000000  Label Start:
200020
400000
.
.
.       push letters
140000  print string
010000  jump to start
```

Answer (score 1):

## [Whitespace](https://web.archive.org/web/20150618184706/http://compsoc.dur.ac.uk/whitespace/tutorial.php), 415 bytes

```
(much whitespace)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##VVDRDgMhCHsuX9FfW5ZLdm9L7pJ9vpOCHCqCQK3V3@e8j@v7eh9jGDmNAH3ADWGx9SCXkVoQZnOFZnIwgNVN3grrvkAKFmhi05Bddj2F7F3U/pGDBebDhsaMppLEXsR68uKstvmf1b@Z6NKjaTVxGr1oi8gzHY6SRKvkuRTowLxizjH@)

```
lssl        label start:
sssttssssstsststtsttstsststttsstttsstsstttssstsssttttsttttsttttsttttsststttsstssststtssssstttsttttsstssttsttssttsttsstsssstssttssssssttttttstttsttsttsttstsstssssssttssststttssttttttstttstssssssttsssttsssssttssttsststttstttttttstststsstsssstttstsstsssstsssstttstttsststsssstssssttttstttssstttssttssstsssstssl
            push base 24 sentence "EASIER COMMUNICATION MEANS FASTER CODING MEANS FEWER CODERS MEANS "
lsssl       label print:
sssttsssl   24
stsstl      copy 1
stsstl      copy 1
tstt        mod
ssststttl   23
tsst        sub
lsl         dup
ltstl       jz space
ssstttsssl  push 56
tsss        add
lsstl       label space:
ssstsssssl  push 32
tsss        add
tlss        printc
tsts        div
sls         dup
ltsl        jz start
lslsl       jump print
```

Comment: Would zero as space be shorter since you wouldn't need the `23 sub dup` part?

Comment: It also works with a zero for space (I did that in my [99 bootles of beer answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/64198/99-bottles-of-beer/194139#194139).) The problem is, the string must not end with a space. It only works [with a leading space](https://tio.run/##XVBbDoAgDPt2p@jVjCHRPxNNPD6y7oXCwrZuLbBnP@52nevWehdgGJZhuiJSR09AQ0bErRS4kczPhtKy9hCzfoeM7tpYZqodH6I/IB4BZGvdn7xs8G9l3W8u@cRQaGnFj0NYE9GZScxFWPKTTIF6ielpxv4/pDmFSRiqY/f@Ag) which is not allowed afaik.

Comment: That makes sense. How about duping the `24` rather than pushing 23 and then subtracting the mod from the duped value and jumping if negative?

Comment: I don't know if I'm understanding something wrong. The mod values are in the range 0-23. If you subtract 24 from that, every value will be negative. If you swap it before subtraction, none of the values will be negative or zero.

Answer (score 1):

## [Husk](https://github.com/barbuz/Husk), 30 bytes

```
¢ma¨ÿȦ3ċṀÏ₁ÄẋΩƒ'ŸċḋÄẋḟω≡¢oΔ₅ṁż
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##yygtzv7//9Ci3MRDKw7vP7HM@Ej3w50Nh/sfNTUebnm4q/vcymOT1I/uAIru6AYLPNwx/3zno86Fhxbln5vyqKn14c7Go3v@/wcA)

The battle of which language has better builtin compression.

Answer (score 1):

## [convey](http://xn--wxa.land/convey/), 69 bytes

```
}'EASIER COMMUNICATION MEANS FASTER CODING MEANS FEWER CODERS MEANS '
```

[Try it online!](https://xn--wxa.land/convey/run.html#eyJjIjoifSdFQVNJRVIgQ09NTVVOSUNBVElPTiBNRUFOUyBGQVNURVIgQ09ESU5HIE1FQU5TIEZFV0VSIENPREVSUyBNRUFOUyAnIiwidiI6MSwiaSI6IiJ9)

convey outputs strings forever, which is usually annoying but sometimes helpful.

Answer (score 1):

## BRASCA, 76 bytes

I should add string compression to BRASCA...

```python
1[x` SNAEM SREDOC REWEF SNAEM GNIDOC RETSAF SNAEM NOITACINUMMOC REISAE`[o]1]
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##zVt7V9vGEv/fn2ILt8UuNpg8moSLaYGQlrZADianvYdDlbW1tpXKWkVaxXD6@Oq5M6uHtdLaWoUn57QBaXfmN8@d3R3512LCvacv/eCzM/V5IEh4HbbJlIpJYxTwKRHOlJH0lcuYHz8OqGfDP8kL/Av@G7NG8kAEdMgGdPhnozF0aRiS/YCGQ3qAv283CPysrKz0BQxok4CNnVCwICRAhXyigUMHLgthgBxosxGxLMdzhGU1Q@aOWtsN@QJ/ViUNOTEjk73EwRuhHNAjF5fqcwrPuuqjgfJozmMvYGTGgAG1HW9M2CcWgNbwVxqS4YSCrMj3@yLjAIZYU24zoPuGuiHL4X7r@MzuOB6xqaDZY2dEPC5NANOB2YYTUiGum63tbEiOPgywcDqQn89AlM3WxfZ2Z@tSmTTiAbHaxCLAlHnRlAVUsGaBVIGRhhnaK4xcgUzVNxfIsl16WsShWmaD@j7z7CYP7GZMuNXKhjPQWZXk4CVzrf5E0YkS4wwY84gPRhDMJtdMFOxDXVTVtZWOKNvofOKEZOa4LgkFBx@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@RlwwxTpYHKTLGSQfPp3iClWuFHDxKdQIYNYS6V3SLRcSpVGdHtlSRkkfKePsLaZWkLUILBUE3e1iJV51lXnJRD351A1TxbTKYPMMLmsxAO8IsIiSjNTMsKiauJBzLmFSiqh6SjoSZ8npy2VYW6nU9HkQsWrb9siT5Zze1zZHflgJhCl9nFhNPvGmBu5B@teQsaaEBmOIBE/A9sWXeyYsA2FLs@FfkxHZGYHKPTplu@W3Q7KDYbPbaJxziCfc3EBoD6Jxm0SQt0b25hBDDbhQG/PNaHO4gUNDl8@IzWce4ZHwI5EMDzeHoQTm4L4IeVqWlNiyphTqYisxYQwADJHbeiVOlmDLKsmVz1sXV@9J/2Tv8Jj0zw5fnx6Qs8PfDt8kj348OYofnff30mcnp0fnewdHJ@@Oj@Wro/7e4fsLfrl1@TnZ3sWJj@xjBotTKia8KfXzGPL5Lc2V5BjkkKPl33G2zGHOauMdmWxzb/LZMbhW7Zw5R57UhYbsZTGLJGOUDd1CTy09WCVypd6BRLqrVrxLklVXE4c5reWr8W45cZSCYcuc3JYBuSfm5J4YkHtqTu6pAbln5uSeGZB7bk7uuQG578zJfWdA7oU5uRcG5F6ak3tpQO6VOblXBuTcGm5sEha/1qBn4nmsRlyYGPewRmCYBJpdIzJMzPu6hi@bxMakhruYePNPdfzFxGF@qUXQhOJfK9tk9TUbBgyLC1Pi6SMsGzsmGfsfZHPk3YDNugmbANnI5e5Mngbr@ND5CqwveyUYk0G4aXFwkyKPnpuDNqGAUm@hBRI6rUZ5wZYCxKs9FFsTGlQKvvZ@baljqGfB2graqBQvSiGPyirKmfWty9YyQkpFtY5bsrJGjiluhX3cCPLcAftC7OvoB3u2fccOoHPZdWrgpx3E148GeE0hHgBkxwTktwjyOHKF47vXDwDyWxOQm3FiEWwM3mM7n5xQty29e7CbmyZov5Yq5Xbk8gfA@LUJxD8Q4uGVz71FifqOrW5k9lAG0MfgJgjLzPHWcWMEG7/k1xAYNGmrpUvS@46YObAfrpGV/kXQJ6fnt4r5XxN1fSPz4cnrB7DnNyb4/kZ8p2cPAO9vE3gWwvv9QfD9Afg03tfXbuJLwCkC9@VBPZ8ffu8tLRXyFw9AwEA9Ay2XfXMuAxMue5JLeqdjJox66WAmzb6ez34NPkbytJFPcgGw4FBG4ZDeFFQS3kbCdoR3rfLAH0ThoyUcvjTz0JuMLKH@r4p6fl9nCjy9wjNFlY6ntzChJM0UpZnyT6r6MT5iIlqW8e3ZFxkjxSZJGOA7zvAVFC0v75KDz2p8dXVujM@v0B/xZGNQqPeLKY88YbqD8@Y7uG47nrpkD2dso9ux09sKOz0iPSz3hRv6w/cyWcY9X0l3Rbez9eSFqd9lDWJN2GcWzxVaBgC@yta4@cVsZdLWnGUkV7cmLP@DLMMZ9aWhxYwTR7BpSLh342R@5xl/YCDfmbQpF@kiJSYBY/cr4/DOFTG8icq09zklPfZRj0Pu4brpZcoEd4kJh/fvJxhjoUCR1vEfahRh46IYix0g6TxANmtrGx@440l2XmueyLKDL@yBWJz0hpjmIJnkUl/uSi@ZXX2iV0c5CN5AHU6iDij7BAEijoMpP8l9zY7ufFwRqp2kaKWHQpFrsVgAJZ682yPPXiZtsfj3To88f7F4nnLiCCwuJBK8@pfTAXS13Ed5ueeNdLEGmuv3JndXFfvVF0sNkBvVYl/J8tcBIoFdXbIv9bsS7d/ztE0Ka5NFvcQlQi7vvE5fS9IzLUNk108czfVO0iEZ2CZ55l2Cc7wQZz6nXMU55aqUUxpVbqC2Rt22mJozgaPNUwNH4/KoRTZ0YPv4Xv/g6Chpk6zyunkrQql3eWE7QkGUctOz9jICf@SQ5nCiXgO12hDWdm9tzcDSpwtFNQmCh5c2C746Qnuq0EkGfbwGzhu3hpgni8V8rMbVGHYusCaeD7gnAu6SNy6fVStkBxXyKwtDqKPpXd@AoPp2aK3EtaWnxExUXbfdaBd18SOYR/bA3486dh@vOnrySudjBG59D4ro9R6tJtb@twaa2Gdixpj3GLaWqC@sLof4v8frQD@gA52zYOrgxqxxO0kRPxljV44wqS1XEQDkQ1v2ElOXfIimfkVil1pHvXYr9VFuQahE9AER/QwosJqbQWEd1ulxUPtnqrn9nHHDbxrrseuo7NYN2F0gu9@w7bUje2bLjdtldcc171dY9C7dYCk7pc7WZYWFFkmVCZVvNq9sptVKe1mQFpbku5J1905FNfGkg@VdPYWP@Mw6hc4Nacaf/UmaDXXnEn/kIqXwAyYPZMLse1f8pjJphyq33Ot7o/Vd9qvn@H2MI6A0HJHZhHmwxefAOJBRJRywKbAdwe7druiPrtdvpX4Hk6E5Rdayh0CeKzuiYZ7MS01YCbhCp8LqsbxCSb/6LH7taZQC2dWQ@YL8wq4HHBIP9toEQeSLwsdT5WyeTDyU/0DaRkMWxFnt8ymLv5adMU@QWcC9cRtPgvkMjEOAE1fhxqX0yuHZ2enZNtFNL9y9xhOy78E3IF1PqbAAXPEQPidC/B3AUeK4yfcPjbobh/lYJQTAxzQ7jKX3vDc4qqS9pVWIBiOGvh5jebNKq/ZsC4jrA3ROm5bJaskl@iyTWyJ2bZGrxa0v6kIx8efz/wE)

### Explanation

```python
1[x                                                                       1]  - Infinite loop 
   ` SNAEM SREDOC REWEF SNAEM GNIDOC RETSAF SNAEM NOITACINUMMOC REISAE`       - Push the string
                                                                       [o]    - Output each character
```

Answer (score 0):

## [Tcl](http://tcl.tk/), 94 bytes

```
while 1 {puts -nonewline "EASIER COMMUNICATION MEANS FASTER CODING MEANS FEWER CODERS MEANS "}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K0nO@f@/PCMzJ1XBUKG6oLSkWEE3Lz8vtTwnMy9VQcnVMdjTNUjB2d/XN9TP09kxxNPfT8HX1dEvWMHNMTgELOXi6ecOE3MNhwi5BgVDhZRq//8HAA)

Answer (score 0):

## Bash 68 bytes

```
f()(printf "%sER CO%s MEANS " EASI MMUNICATION FAST DING FEW DERS;f)
```

[Try it online](https://tio.run/##BcFBCoAgEAXQq3wEQc/QatAxXGigRutaSG0isvtP7x37OEW6seZ5r/vrUHpwgVv0QGLKFQpMNSKlNUdHLS4ZgWqDj3lG4A2eS526lS4/)

Answer (score 0):

## [brainfuck](https://github.com/TryItOnline/brainfuck), 657 bytes

```
+[++++[++++>---<]>++.----.>-[--->+<]>--.----------.----.+++++++++++++.--[----->++<]>.+[->++<]>+.[->+++++<]>.--..++++++++.-------.-----.------.--.>-[--->+<]>-.-----------.++++++.-.++[----->++<]>.++++++[->++<]>+.--------.----.+++++++++++++.+++++.+[--->+<]>++++.+++[->++<]>.-----.>-[--->+<]>--.+.[----->+<]>+.+++++++++++++.--[----->++<]>.+[->++<]>+.[->+++++<]>.-----------.+++++.+++++.-------.+[->++++<]>.++++++[->++<]>+.--------.----.+++++++++++++.+++++.+[--->+<]>++++.+++[->++<]>.-.>+[--->++<]>+.++[----->+<]>.+++++++++++++.--[----->++<]>.+[->++<]>+.[->+++++<]>.-----------.+.+++++++++++++.+.+[--->+<]>++++.++++++[->++<]>+.--------.----.+++++++++++++.+++++.]
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##rVBbCsMwDDuQsE9QfJHQj60wGIN9DHr@TE3tNAljsIc/Ese2LCnnx@l6v6zLLWckMMphIjLNBigTUZPEy8ASX1Jj76INllLpEcxxRfIMWjLsZcK0gRzbYr0OtA1rMOqW9GQlDsZ3Ov2sDFEMtKvprW8mpCK@dD740P4T4MP/96Pm3RDfePndyijnhZQPvcw5PwE)

Answer (score 0):

## APL NARS, 152 bytes, 76 chars

```
f
A:⍞←'EASIER COMMUNICATION MEANS FASTER CODING MEANS FEWER CODERS MEANS '⋄→A
```

I don't know if there are some leak or the buffer for output is buffered in a way increase its size.
Possible i see it wrong but it seems that the size mem in NARS increase, and afther some second
the output of the line disappear.

Comment: You don't need to count the `f` (or the newline, which you didn't count anyway), by every character is two bytes in NARS, so 75 chars=150 bytes.

Comment: Shorter: `→≡⍞←'EASIER COMMUNICATION MEANS FASTER CODING MEANS FEWER CODERS MEANS '`

Comment: →⍞←'EASIER.... Why not this?

Comment: Because `→` needs a line number to go to. Text is not a line number, but its depth (1) is the number you need.

Answer (score 0):

## [MathGolf](https://github.com/maxbergmark/mathgolf), 74 bytes

```
1{"EASIER COMMUNICATION MEANS FASTER CODING MEANS FEWER CODERS MEANS "_q}∟
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y00syUjPz0n7/9@wWsnVMdjTNUjB2d/XN9TP09kxxNPfT8HX1dEvWMHNMTgELOXi6ecOE3MNhwi5BgVDhZTiC2sfdcz//x8A)

Explantion:

```
1                                                                          Loop condition
 {                                                                         Start block
  "EASIER COMMUNICATION MEANS FASTER CODING MEANS FEWER CODERS MEANS "_q   Output the string
                                                                        }∟ Do without popping
```

Comment: Mathgolf *does* have both a compressed string literal command as well as a dictionary lookup, either of which should shorten this somewhat (though I have no experience with them)

Comment: None of those methods (compressed string literals (they only support lowercase letters) and dictionary lookups (none of those words are completely upper-case)) can compress capital lettters. In addition, there isn't a built-in in MathGolf that will capitalize a whole string.

Comment: Huh, that's weird, though you could use `mδ` (map capitalise) to do so

Comment: Huh, this is weird, dictionary compression is actually [longer](https://tio.run/##ARoA5f9tYXRoZ29sZv//w7vDpuKGlSTilaZtzrT//w) than an uncompressed string.

Comment: @JoKing Sorry, my [compressed string](https://tio.run/##y00syUjPz0n7///R1KmPZuxOeTR10aOGReoKIHpK06Opi42BEocnegNJRefDu/0Uwg9v1Hg0dRlIxdRzkxMR6qcC1R9eop4H1PNo@kwkZYvObVQvR1PXDuSXAVUe3gWxN0xdIbY699yW2tjK//8B) is as long as the program.

Answer (score 0):

## Batch 116 bytes

```bat
@echo off&Set M= MEANS &Set C=ER CO
For /L %%i in ()Do <nul Set/P =EASI%C%MMUNICATION%M%FAST%C%DING%M%FEW%C%DERS%M%
```

How:

- `For /L %%i in ()Do` enacts an infinite loop
- `nul set/p =` prints the trailing string without a newline.