# Easier communication means… ○ circular edition!

Tags: code-golf, kolmogorov-complexity, graphical-output, animation, typography

Based on [this](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/119361/easier-communication-means-faster-coding-means-fewer-coders-means/119406), but I was asked<sup>[[​1​]](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/119361/easier-communication-means-faster-coding-means-fewer-coders-means#comment292359_119361),[[​2​]](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/119361/easier-communication-means-faster-coding-means-fewer-coders-means#comment292548_119406)</sup> to do a graphical edition.

[image: EASIER COMMUNICATION MEANS FASTER CODING MEANS FEWER CODERS MEANS…]

## Task

**Generate a circular display of the text `EASIER COMMUNICATION MEANS FASTER CODING MEANS FEWER CODERS MEANS` .** Any uppercase font goes. The letter tops must face out of the circle. Either the space before `FEWER` must be at the bottom (6 o'clock) or (for brownie points) your text must rotate.

Comment: @Uriel Well, nominally, each letter takes 5.45°, so shall we say 5.4° to 5.5°?

Comment: I believe that would be a good precision, considering the `2/21` approximation error is small than 0.002.

Answer (score 7):

## Octave, 168 bytes

```
for i=1:(n=nnz(s='CATION MEANS FASTER CODING MEANS FEWER CODERS MEANS EASIER COMMUNI')),text(sin(i/n*2*pi),cos(i/n*2*pi),s(i),'rotation',-i/n*360);axis([-2,2,-2,2]);end
```

**[Try it here](http://octave-online.net/#cmd=for%20i%3D1%3A(n%3Dnnz(s%3D%27CATION%20MEANS%20FASTER%20CODING%20MEANS%20FEWER%20CODERS%20MEANS%20EASIER%20COMMUNI%27))%2Ctext(sin(i%2Fn*2*pi)%2Ccos(i%2Fn*2*pi)%2Cs(i)%2C%27rotation%27%2C-i%2Fn*360)%3Baxis(%5B-2%2C2%2C-2%2C2%5D)%3Bend)**

Comment: Nice! It seems `axis([-2,2,-2,2]);` is not needed. But you may want to add `axis equal` at the end to get a true circle

Comment: what do you do with the for loop? Can you add an explanation for an Octave novice like me?

Comment: Of course, I'll add an explanation when I have the time. Hopefully later today :-)

Answer (score 7):

### Mathematica, 153 Bytes

```
x=Pi/33;Graphics@Map[StringSplit["CATION MEANS FASTER CODING MEANS FEWER CODERS MEANS EASIER COMMUNI",""][[#/x]]~Text~{Sin@#,Cos@#}~Rotate~-#&,Range@66x]
```

[image]

Increasing it to 178 bytes lets it rotate:

```
x=Pi/33;Graphics@Map[StringSplit["CATION MEANS FASTER CODING MEANS FEWER CODERS MEANS EASIER COMMUNI",""][[#/x-a]]~Text~{Sin@#,Cos@#}~Rotate~-#&,(a+Range@66)x]~Animate~{a,1,66,1}
```

[image]

Answer (score 6):

## HTML and JS, 13 + 170 = <s>284</s> <s>227</s> <s>192</s> <s>186</s> 183  bytes

*41 bytes saved thanks to @Shaggy*

```js
(x=c.getContext("2d")).translate(r=c.height/2,r)
for(i in t="CATION MEANS FASTER CODING MEANS FEWER CODERS MEANS EASIER COMMUNI"){x.rotate(2/21);x.fillText(t[i],0,-r*.8)}
```

```html
<canvas id=c height=250 width=250>
```

<sub>The width and height set to 250 to allow better visibility were not included in the bytes count.</sub>

Comment: Reduce your JS to 223 bytes with `(x=c.getContext("2d"))[t="translate"](r=c.height/2,r,i=66);r*=.8;while(i--){x.rotate(a=i*Math.PI/33);x[t](0,-r);x.fillText("EASIER COMMUNICATION MEANS FASTER CODING MEANS FEWER CODERS MEANS "[i],0,0);x[t](0,r);x.rotate(-a)}`.

Comment: Or, reduce the latest version of your JS to 179 bytes with `(x=c.getContext("2d")).translate(r=c.height/2,r);r*=.8;for(i in t="EASIER COMMUNICATION MEANS FASTER CODING MEANS FEWER CODERS MEANS "){x.rotate(Math.PI/33);x.fillText(t[i],0,-r)}`

Comment: If you're happy to sacrifice a little bit of precision, you could replace `Math.PI` with `22/7` to save another 6 bytes.

Comment: and `Math.PI/33` ≈ `2/21`, but is that considered ok?

Comment: You might need to run it past @Adám for confirmation.

Comment: @Uriel `2/21` is fine. I can't tell the difference.

Comment: You can save some bytes using es6 `for...of`: `for(c of"CATION...` and `x.fillText(c,`

Answer (score 5):

## Bash + ImageMagick, 168 bytes

```bash
convert -font $(convert -list font|grep Font:|head -n1|cut -d" " -f4) label:"FEWER CODERS MEANS EASIER COMMUNICATION MEANS FASTER CODING MEANS " -distort Arc 360 i.png
```

**Example output:**

[image: Example output]

Comment: I think you can use a fixed font name to shorten it.

Answer (score 5):

## BBC BASIC, 248

Download interpreter at http://www.bbcbasic.co.uk/bbcwin/download.html

```
F.i=6TO767a=i DIV6*.024-.3r=(80+i MOD6)MOD83*9-369IFASC(M."?[O@Wo}@b}O@O|O@y?l@xHH@GGE@zmo@yo|@}oU@o?m@?L|@phh@GEE@?u?@?{o@Wk?@?I?@g|O@EGE@?]M@z}o@|_|@}?m@?MO@GDG@xhh@?k?@?oU@z}o@?LO@a?L",i DIV6))>>i MOD6A.1CIRCLEFILL500-r*COS(a),500+r*SIN(a),9
N.
```

**Ungolfed**

```
  FORi=6TO767
    a=i DIV 6 * .024 - .3
    r=(80 + i MOD 6) MOD 83 * 9 - 369            :REM iterate through ({80,81,82,0,1,2} - 41 = {39,40,41,-41,-40,-39}) * 9
    IF ASC(MID$("?[O@Wo}@b}O@O|O@y?l@xHH@GGE@zmo@yo|@}oU@o?m@?L|@phh@GEE@?u?@?{o@Wk?@?I?@g|O@EGE@?]M@z}o@|_|@}?m@?MO@GDG@xhh@?k?@?oU@z}o@?LO@a?L",i DIV6))>>i MOD6AND1    THEN
      CIRCLEFILL 500-r*COS(a), 500+r*SIN(a), 9   :REM dots are circle radius 9 according to documentation (but BBC BASIC actually draws them smaller.)
    ENDIF
  NEXT
```

Doing this in a language that doesn't support rotated text - for fun. Each character is a 3x3 dot matrix array. There are a total of 66 characters but there are 2 diametrically opposite spaces that we do not print (after CODERS and before FASTER.) Each byte of the magic string encodes for a single vertical row of one letter and a single vertical row of the opposite letter. In this way we only have to sweep through 180 degrees.

[image]

Comment: Clever, but you should be able to do 4 pixels high letters in a byte, no? Also, your text should be rotated 5 characters counter-clockwise.

Comment: @Adám difficult to do 4 pixels high as code will contain many unprintables.  I don't think the interpreter will like it. I misinterpreted/misremembered the spec for rotation. (`MEANS` was already at the bottom and I rotated it the wrong way) `+.2` needs to be changed to `-.3` Editing.

Comment: Since the OP specifies uppercase, maybe do A as **⠰⠳** and R as **⠸⠫**?

Comment: @Adam that's a lot of extra work now, and I believe it will reduce readability. It's common in arty and calculator fonts for certain uppercase letters to be replaced with equivalents resembling lowercase. I will see how it looks later.

Answer (score 3):

### SVG(HTML5), 212 bytes

```html
<svg width=500 height=500><defs><path id=p d=M250,451a201,201,0,0,1,0,-402a201,201,0,0,1,0,402></defs><text font-size="32"><textPath xlink:href=#p>FEWER CODERS MEANS EASIER COMMUNICATION MEANS FASTER CODING MEANS
```

Static version of my answer to [Easier communication means faster coding means fewer coders means …](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/119361) tweaked so that `FEWER` is at the bottom. Adjustable version in case your font doesn't match mine:

```html
<p><input type=number value=0 min=0 max=9 oninput=p.setAttribute('d','M250,250m0,20_a20_,20_,0,1,1,20_,-20_a20_,20_,0,1,1,-20_,-20_a20_,20_,0,1,1,-20_,20_a20_,20_,0,1,1,20_,20_'.replace(/_/g,this.value))></p>
<svg width=500 height=500><defs><path id=p d=M250,250m0,200a200,200,0,1,1,200,-200a200,200,0,1,1,-200,-200a200,200,0,1,1,-200,200a200,200,0,1,1,200,200></defs><text font-size="32"><textPath xlink:href=#p>FEWER CODERS MEANS EASIER COMMUNICATION MEANS FASTER CODING MEANS
```

Comment: How do you adjust the spacing between *MEANS* and *FEWER*? In my browser, they read like one word.

Comment: @Adám I've ported the adjustable version across.

Comment: Nice. That's going over and beyond.

Answer (score 2):

## Postscript (127 bytes)

Hex dump:

```
00000000: 2f53 2031 92a5 9233 2f4d 6f6e 6f20 3992  /S 1...3/Mono 9.
00000010: 8e88 6432 3030 926b 3292 9a28 4943 4154  ..d200.k2..(ICAT
00000020: 494f 4e20 4d45 414e 5320 4641 5354 4552  ION MEANS FASTER
00000030: 2043 4f44 494e 4720 4d45 414e 5320 4645   CODING MEANS FE
00000040: 5745 5220 434f 4445 5253 204d 4541 4e53  WER CODERS MEANS
00000050: 2045 4153 4945 5220 434f 4d4d 554e 297b   EASIER COMMUN){
00000060: 5388 0033 2032 9287 9278 5320 6661 6c73  S..3 2...xS fals
00000070: 6592 112d 352e 3435 9288 7d92 4992 a7    e..-5.45..}.I..
```

Ungolfed (text) version:

```
/S 1 string def
/Mono 9 selectfont
100 200 moveto
2 setlinejoin
(ICATION MEANS FASTER CODING MEANS FEWER CODERS MEANS EASIER COMMUN)
{S 0 3 2 roll put S false charpath -5.45 rotate} forall
stroke
```

Sample output:

[image]

Comment: You can golf this down to 106 bytes, or 148 without binary tokens. ```()9 selectfont 100 200 moveto(ICATION MEANS FASTER CODING MEANS FEWER CODERS MEANS EASIER COMMUN){(.)dup 0 4 3 roll put show -5.47 rotate}forall``` is 148 bytes, which tokenizes down to 106 bytes, which ```xxd -ps``` renders as ```282939928e8864323030926b2849434154494f4e204d45414e5320464153
54455220434f44494e47204d45414e5320464557455220434f4445525320
4d45414e532045415349455220434f4d4d554e297b282e29923830880433
9287927892a02d352e343792887d9249```.

Answer (score 2):

## Java 8, 1,087 bytes

```
import javafx.animation.*;import javafx.application.*;import javafx.scene.*;import javafx.scene.layout.*;import javafx.scene.shape.*;import javafx.scene.text.*;import javafx.stage.*;import javafx.util.*;import java.util.*;import static javafx.animation.PathTransition.*;public class P extends Application{@Override public void start(Stage stage)throws Error{char[] t="EASIER COMMUNICATION MEANS FASTER CODING MEANS FEWER CODERS MEANS".toCharArray();Shape q=new Circle(400,400,120);List<Text>h=new ArrayList<>();List<Transition>z=new ArrayList<>();for(char c:t){Text o=new Text(c+"");h.add(o);z.add(x(q, o));}Pane p=new Pane();p.getChildren().addAll(h);int s=h.size();for(int i=0;i<s;i++){Transition w=z.get(i);w.jumpTo(Duration.seconds(10).multiply((i+.5)*1/s));w.play();}stage.setScene(new Scene(p,800,800));stage.show();}Transition x(Shape e,Text t){PathTransition v=new PathTransition(Duration.seconds(10),e,t);v.setCycleCount(INDEFINITE);v.setOrientation(OrientationType.ORTHOGONAL_TO_TANGENT);v.setInterpolator(Interpolator.LINEAR);return v;}static void main(String[]a){launch(a);}}
```

[image: Screenshot]

Comment: Nice, but you seem to be missing a space between MEANS and EASIER COM.

Comment: @Adám: It does not conform with the FEWER at 6 o'clock rule!

Answer (score 1):

## LaTeX + TikZ, 380 bytes

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=20pt]{standalone}\usetikzlibrary{decorations,decorations.text,}\begin{document}\begin{tikzpicture}\draw[color=white,rotate=-90,postaction={decorate,decoration={text along path,raise=4pt,text align={align=center},text={FEWER CODERS MEANS EASIER COMMUNICATION MEANS FASTER CODING MEANS },reverse path}}](0,0)circle(2.425cm);\end{tikzpicture}\end{document}
```

Example output

[image]

Answer (score 0):

## Tcl/Tk, 222

```
grid [canvas .c]
set i 90;lmap c [split "FEWER CODERS MEANS EASIER COMMUNICATION MEANS FASTER CODING MEANS" ""] {.c cr t [expr {93*cos([set i [expr $i+5.5]]/57.3)+99}] [expr {93*sin($i/57.3)+99}] -te $c -ang [expr -$i-90]}
```

[image]

Will golf it more later!

Answer (score 0):

## Java 10, 690 bytes

```java
import java.awt.*;v->new Frame(){{add(new Panel(){RenderingHints R;Math M;public void paint(Graphics g){Graphics2D G=(Graphics2D)g;G.setRenderingHint(R.KEY_ANTIALIASING,R.VALUE_ANTIALIAS_ON);var v=new Font("Hei",0,8).createGlyphVector(G.getFontRenderContext(),"ICATION MEANS FASTER CODING MEANS FEWER CODERS MEANS EASIER COMMUN");int n=99,i=0;for(G.translate(n,0);i<66;){double p=M.PI/2,t=-6/1.1*i*p/90+p;v.setGlyphPosition(i,new Point(0,0));var a=java.awt.geom.AffineTransform.getTranslateInstance((int)(n*M.cos(t)+n),(int)(-n*M.sin(t)+n));a.rotate(t=4*p*i/66);a.translate(n*M.cos(p-t),n*M.sin(p-t));a.translate(-4,0);G.fill(a.createTransformedShape(v.getGlyphOutline(i++)));}}});show();}}
```

Result:

[image]

**Explanation:**

```java
import java.awt.*;              // Required import for almost everything
v->                             // Method with empty unused parameter and Frame return-type
  new Frame(){                  //  Create the Frame
   {                            //   In an inner code-block:
     add(new Panel(){           //    Add a Panel we can draw on:
       RenderingHints R;        //    RenderingHints null-instance on class-level, for static calls
       Math M;                  //    Math null-instance on class-level, for static calls
       public void paint(Graphics g){
                                //     Overwrite its paint method:
         Graphics2D G=(Graphics2D)g;
                                //      Cast Graphics to Graphics2D, to open up more methods
         G.setRenderingHint(R.KEY_ANTIALIASING,R.VALUE_ANTIALIAS_ON);
                                //      Apply a focus rendering, otherwise the text would be too vague
         var v=new Font("Hei",0,//      Create a "Hei"-Font (could alternatively be Kai)
                                //      (note that a centered monospace font would look a lot better
                                //       for letters like the 'I's)
               8)               //      of font-size 8
               .createGlyphVector(G.getFontRenderContext(),
                                //      Create a GlyphVector using that Font
           "ICATION MEANS FASTER CODING MEANS FEWER CODERS MEANS EASIER COMMUN");
                                //      With this String as text (first character will be at the top)
         int n=99,              //      Integer we'll use a bunch of times, radius of the circle 99
             i=0;               //      Index integer, starting at 0
         for(G.translate(n,0);  //      Set the starting coordinate at 99,0, otherwise the circle
                                //      would be partially outside of the Frame boundaries
             i<66;){            //      Loop `i` in the range [0, 66):
                                //      (66 is the amount of characters of the text)
           double p=M.PI/2,     //       Temp-double `p`, set to PI/2
                  t=            //       Temp-double, which will start at:
                    -6/1.1      //        -360 / 66
                    *i          //        multiplied by the current `i`
                    *p/90       //        multiplied by PI/180
                    +p;         //        And add PI/2 to that
           v.setGlyphPosition(i,new Point(0,0));
                                //        Start the `i`'th Glyph position at 0,0
           var a=java.awt.geom.AffineTransform.getTranslateInstance(
                                //        Create an AffineTransform Translation instance, starting at:
                  (int)(        //         x-coordinate as casted integer:
                   n            //          99
                   *M.cos(t)    //          multiplied by the cosine of `t`
                   +n),         //          Add 99 to that
                  (int)(        //         y-coordinate as casted integer:
                   -n           //          -99
                   *M.sin(t)    //          multiplied by the sinus of `t`
                   +n));        //          Add 99 to that
           a.rotate(            //         Then rotate the current letter by,
                    t=          //         and set `t` to it at the same time:
                      4*p       //          2*PI
                      *i        //          multiplied by the current `i`
                      /66);     //          divided by the length 66
           a.translate(         //         Then move the letter to the correct position:
                                //          x-coordinate:
              n                 //           99
              *M.cos(p-t),      //           multiplied by the cosine of PI/2 - the new `t`
                                //          y-coordinate:
              n                 //           99
              *M.sin(p-t));     //           multiplied by the sinus of PI/2 - the new `t`
           a.translate(-4,0);   //          Slightly adjust based on the font-size
           G.fill(              //          Then add to the Panel through the Graphics2D:
             a.createTransformedShape(
                                //           The shape of:
               v.getGlyphOutline(i++)));}}});
                                //            The current `i`'th Glyph we just created
     show();}}                  //    And afterwards show the Frame
```