# x bottles of y on the z

Tags: code-golf, string

*I do not believe this question to be a duplicate of [this one](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/64198), since this one requires more string manipulation, if it is still a duplicate feel free to close this question*

## Introduction

Your challenge today is to output the lyrics of "99 bottles of beer":

```
99 bottles of beer on the wall, 99 bottles of beer.
Take one down and pass it around, 98 bottles of beer on the wall.

98 bottles of beer on the wall, 98 bottles of beer.
Take one down and pass it around, 97 bottles of beer on the wall.

97 bottles of beer on the wall, 97 bottles of beer.
Take one down and pass it around, 96 bottles of beer on the wall.

96 bottles of beer on the wall, 96 bottles of beer.
Take one down and pass it around, 95 bottles of beer on the wall.

95 bottles of beer on the wall, 95 bottles of beer.
Take one down and pass it around, 94 bottles of beer on the wall.

....

3 bottles of beer on the wall, 3 bottles of beer.
Take one down and pass it around, 2 bottles of beer on the wall.

2 bottles of beer on the wall, 2 bottles of beer.
Take one down and pass it around, 1 bottle of beer on the wall.

1 bottle of beer on the wall, 1 bottle of beer.
Go to the store and buy some more, 99 bottles of beer on the wall.
```

But the twist is that you wont always start from 99, and you wont always buy some more beer from the store, because they don't have infinitely many bottles of beer you know!

## Input

A positive integer *x* > 1, a string *y* and a string *z*

## Output and Test Cases

A string containing the lyrics of the song except that instead of starting from 99 bottles of beer, you start from *x* bottles of *y*, and the *y*s are on the *z*. So given a value of *x* equal to 3, *y* equal to "Pepsi", and *z* equal to "fridge" your output should be:

```
3 bottles of Pepsi on the fridge, 3 bottles of Pepsi.
Take one down and pass it around, 2 bottles of Pepsi on the fridge.

2 bottles of Pepsi on the fridge, 2 bottles of Pepsi.
Take one down and pass it around, 1 bottle of Pepsi on the fridge.

1 bottle of Pepsi on the fridge, 1 bottle of Pepsi.
Go to the store and buy some more, 3 bottles of Pepsi on the fridge.
```

## Scoring

Lowest byte count wins.

Comment: [Here's the original](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/64198/99-bottles-of-beer/) for inspiration. Is this too similar?

Comment: I'm on the fence as to whether this is different enough than the plain 99BB challenge, but since my vote is a hammer I won't close-vote it as yet.

Comment: (You use **x** in one place and **n** in another, please fix). Does my program need to handle only **n** up to 99? Or 9,999? *2,147,483,647*?

Comment: @BradC You need to handle any values of x, also will fix

Comment: @AdmBorkBork I believe since this one involves more string manipulation it should be different enough don't you think?

Comment: I think the only changes I'd need to make from my beer on the wall code is to take an input in place of 99 as the initial counter value, and store it to put into the last line. That, and replace some text strings.

Comment: This is uninspired, to say the very least. Is it original? **No.** Is it interesting? **No.** Does it add anything **new** or **exciting** to the other, **similar**, challenge? **No.** Is it similar? **Yes.** Should we close it? **Probably.** That being said, don't let this dissuade you from writing more challenges, just, probably, spend more time on them and make them interesting.

Comment: The major thing that people don't like about similarities too is that you can strip code from the old answer and paste it into the new answer. For instance, 05AB1E compresses words and in the 05AB1E answer I can take all the work that user did compressing "bottles of - on the - take one down pass it around" and directly rip that.

Comment: @MagicOctopusUrn "Does it add anything new or exciting to the other, similar, challenge?", exiciting is subjective, but it does add something new.

Comment: @FireCubez yes, it's subjective, but would you honestly call this exciting? Plug-and-play strings for an existing question? Meh... I was just pointing out that this is usually the tie breaker between closing/keeping open when people are asking "is it different enough". While it's subjective, trivial edits to questions that are interesting/exciting have passed, while in my personal opinion this isn't very interesting (and the 99 bottles question is super famous / still competed on - last post Oct 24 at 14:18). Not trying to be mean, just pointing out what I wish people told me when I was newer!

Comment: I actually posted a rick-roll duplicate my first question and got rep-bombed lol.

Comment: @MagicOctopusUrn lol.