# Rocket Liftoff!

Tags: code-golf, kolmogorov-complexity

This code golf challenge is about making a rocket liftoff sequence.

Your output (STDOUT) should be equal to this:

```
Liftoff in T-10
Liftoff in T-9
Liftoff in T-8
Liftoff in T-7
Liftoff in T-6
Liftoff in T-5
Liftoff in T-4
Liftoff in T-3
Liftoff in T-2
Liftoff in T-1
LIFTOFF!
```

Rules:

- Your output must print to STDOUT.
- Your program must not raise any errors.
- This is code golf, shortest code in bytes wins.

Comment: What does it mean for the output to be "similar to this"? You should specify it exactly. And is the "..." in the output something we actually print verbatim, or does it stand for the middle part of the sequence?

Comment: Welcome to Code Golf! We have a couple of default rules that should not be overridden unless there's a good reason to because of the nature of the challenge (which is not the case here). For instance, code golf submissions are [programs or functions](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/a/2422/58563) by default and [you should not make assumptions about languages features](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/a/8067/58563).

Comment: Does this look better?

Comment: I'd be very surprised if this isn't a dupe. Personally, I'd consider it VTC-as-dupe worthy for any challenge that required you to count down from an input to `0`, but until such a post is found, I'll VTRO

Comment: I agree, as it is, this is a pretty common challenge. Could benefit of some twist. For example, having a delay between lines, or the countdown to get randomly interrupted by “launch cancelled” message.

Comment: @manatwork While either of those twists would make it new I don't think either of them would benefit the challenge at all.  It's better to just come up with a new challenge than try to add a twist to a bad one.

Comment: ooo @manatwork good one! probs gonna add that... but wouldnt that affect current responses?

Comment: sorry for the low quality, this is my first question on code golf. thanks for the help!

Comment: @ExplorPython, I wrote that comment while the challenge was still closed. Once reopened better don't touch the rules.

Comment: ok! sounds good.

Comment: Does this answer your question? ["99 Bottles of Beer"](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/64198/99-bottles-of-beer)

Answer (score 5):

## [Java (JDK)](http://jdk.java.net/), <s>92</s> <s>79</s> 78 bytes

```java
v->{for(int i=11;i-->0;)System.out.println(i>0?"Liftoff in T-"+i:"LIFTOFF!");}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##LY6xCsIwFEV3v@LZqUUS6mq0DkJBqDgoLuIQYyOvpklpXgoi/fYaxPXeyz2nkYNkzeM1deFuUIEy0ns4SLTwmQF4khTTJq54IDRcB6sIneU7Z31o6359cfgoQMNmGljx0a5P0RLgZrkUyFiRi@z09lS33AXiXR9LY1Ms8m1SoSanNUTWmSULXCXVvjwfy3KeZGKcAMRf6m8xRBK0US09Ufx5Xm8g@6fPfqYAmkul6o5SG4zJRMzG2Th9AQ)

Edit: Thanks to @KevinCruijssen for -1 byte

Comment: `--i>=0` to `i-->0` for -1 byte. :)

Answer (score 3):

## [APL (Dyalog Unicode)](https://www.dyalog.com/), 36 [bytes](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/a/9429/43319) ([SBCS](https://github.com/abrudz/SBCS))

Full program.

```apl
↑'Liftoff in T-'∘,∘⍕¨⌽⍳10
'LIFTOFF!'
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##SyzI0U2pTMzJT///qKO94P@jtonqPplpJflpaQqZeQohuuqPOmboAPGj3qmHVjzq2fuod7OhAZe6j6dbiL@bm6I6SNt/BTAoAAA)

`⍳` **ɩ**ndices 1 through 10
`⌽` reverse them
`¨` on each number, do:
 `⍕` format as text
 `∘` then:
  `,` prepend
  `∘` the entirety of:
   `'Liftoff in T-'` this string
`↑` merge list of strings into character matrix (and implicitly output to stdout)

`'LIFTOFF!'` this string (implicitly output it to stdout)

Comment: I've seen it before, but how do you even post an answer if the question is already closed.. It's closed 19 minutes ago, yet your answer is from 7 minutes ago.. :S

Comment: Why is `0` included in the string?

Comment: @KevinCruijssen, you can still post from the mobile app if you don't refresh first.

Comment: @vrintle Fixed. Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

## [Python 2](https://docs.python.org/2/), 56 bytes

```python
d=11
exec"'Liftoff in T-%d'%d;d-=1;print"*d+"'LIFTOFF!'"
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K6gsycjPM/r/P8XW0JArtSI1WUndJzOtJD8tTSEzTyFEVzVFXTXFOkXX1tC6oCgzr0RJK0UbqMTTLcTfzU1RXen/fwA)

Wonderful application of [Using exec to remove repeated print](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/204550/48931).

-1 thanks to dingledooper who realised we can reuse the `d` variable in the exec multiplier.

### [Python 2](https://docs.python.org/2/), 57 bytes

```python
d=~9
while d:print"Liftoff in T%d"%d;d+=1
print"LIFTOFF!"
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K6gsycjPM/r/P8W2zpKrPCMzJ1UhxaqgKDOvRMknM60kPy1NITNPIUQ1RUk1xTpF29aQCyrp6Rbi7@amqPT/PwA)

### [Python 2](https://docs.python.org/2/), 59 bytes

```python
d=10
while d:print"Liftoff in T-%d"%d+1/d*"\nLIFTOFF!";d-=1
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K6gsycjPM/r/P8XW0ICrPCMzJ1UhxaqgKDOvRMknM60kPy1NITNPIURXNUVJNUXbUD9FSykmz8fTLcTfzU1RyTpF19bw/38A)

Comment: Wonderful! I believe you can save one more byte [Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K6gsycjPM/r/P8XW0JArtSI1WUndJzOtJD8tTSEzTyFEVzVFXTXFOkXX1tC6oCgzr0RJK0UbqMTTLcTfzU1RXen/fwA)

Comment: @dingledooper That's beautiful. Love it!

Answer (score 2):

## [Ruby 2.7](https://www.ruby-lang.org/), <sup>51</sup> 50 bytes

*Saved a byte using* `~9` *for* `-10`*, thanks to [Sisyphus](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/48931/sisyphus)!*

```ruby
puts (~9..-1).map{"Liftoff in T#{_1}"}<<"LIFTOFF!"
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##KypNqvz/v6C0pFhBo85ST0/XUFMvN7GguiazRsknM60kPy1NITNPIUS5OrNWqdbGRsnH0y3E381NUen/fwA)

TIO uses an older version of Ruby, whereas in Ruby 2.7, we've numbered parameters, which saves two bytes.

---

## [Ruby](https://www.ruby-lang.org/), 57 bytes

```ruby
puts"Liftoff in T-#{11-($.+=1)}"while$.<10
puts"LIFTOFF!"
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##KypNqvz/v6C0pFjJJzOtJD8tTSEzTyFEV7na0FBXQ0VP29ZQs1apPCMzJ1VFz8bQgAui1NMtxN/NTVHp/38A)

Comment: For the 51 character version better mention that uses Ruby 2.7 [numbered block parameter](https://rubyreferences.github.io/rubychanges/2.7.html#numbered-block-parameters), for people to know why it doesn't work on TIO's Ruby 2.5.5.

Comment: Thanks @manatwork, I really forgot to add it.

Comment: `-10` -> `~9` for -1 byte

Comment: Nice, @Sisyphus ;-)

Answer (score 2):

## Bash, 67 bytes

```bash
for i in `seq 10`;do echo Liftoff in T-$((11-i));done;echo LIFTOFF!
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S0oszvj/Py2/SCFTITNPIaE4tVDB0DDBOiVfITU5I1/BJzOtJD8tDSQXoquioWFoqJupqQmUzku1hijwdAvxd3NT/P8fAA)

## Bash, 43 bytes

thanks to @Sisyphus for this suggestion.

```bash
seq -f'Liftoff in T%g' -10 -1;echo LIFTOFF!
```

[Try it online](https://tio.run/##S0oszvj/vzi1UEE3Td0nM60kPy1NITNPIUQ1XV1B19AAiK1TkzPyFXw83UL83dwU//8HAA)

Comment: You're not supposed to include 0.

Comment: [43 bytes](https://tio.run/##S0oszvj/vzi1UEE3Td0nM60kPy1NITNPIUQ1XV1B19AAiK1TkzPyFXw83UL83dwU//8HAA "Bash – Try It Online")

Answer (score 1):

## [Perl 5](https://www.perl.org/), 43 bytes

```perl
say"Liftoff in T$_"for-10..-1;say'LIFTOFF!'
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K0gtyjH9/784sVLJJzOtJD8tTSEzTyFEJV4pLb9I19BAT0/X0Booq@7j6Rbi7@amqP7//7/8gpLM/Lzi/7q@pnoGhgYA)

Answer (score 1):

## [PowerShell Core](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell), 37 bytes

```powershell
10..1|%{"Liftoff in T-$_"}
"LIFTOFF!"
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K8gvTy0qzkjNydFNzi9K/f/f0EBPz7BGtVrJJzOtJD8tTSEzTyFEVyVeqZZLycfTLcTfzU1R6f9/AA)

Answer (score 1):

## [Jelly](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly), <strike>25</strike> 24 bytes

```
“ÞÆdḂbMG:ȯ»;Ɱ⁵ṚY⁷“KçÞ»Œu
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##ATcAyP9qZWxsef//4oCcw57DhmThuIJiTUc6yK/Cuzvisa7igbXhuZpZ4oG34oCcS8Onw57Cu8WSdf//)

*-1 byte thanks to caird*

### Explanation

```
“ÞÆdḂbMG:ȯ»;Ɱ⁵ṚY⁷“KçÞ»Œu   Main niladic link
“ÞÆdḂbMG:ȯ»                "Liftoff in T-"
           ;               Join with
            Ɱ              each of
             ⁵             [1 to] 10
              Ṛ            Reverse
               Y           Join with newlines
                           Print and discard
                ⁷          Newline
                           Print and discard
                 “KçÞ»     "liftoff!"
                      Œu   Uppercase
```

Comment: [-1 byte](https://tio.run/##ATcAyP9qZWxsef//4oCcw57DhmThuIJiTUc6yK/Cuzvisa7igbXhuZpZ4oG34oCcS8Onw57Cu8WSdf//)

Comment: @cairdcoinheringaahing Thanks! I've been confused by unpaired nilads in links and I think this clears them up.

Comment: They're mainly very helpful if you just want to print and discard something :)

Answer (score 1):

## [Nim](http://nim-lang.org/), <strike>54</strike> 53 bytes

```
for i in -10..<0:echo "Liftoff in T",i
echo"LIFTOFF!"
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y8vM/f8/Lb9IIVMhM09B19BAT8/GwCo1OSNfQcknM60kPy0NJBGipJPJBRJV8vF0C/F3c1NU@v8fAA)

*-1 byte by using the negative numbers trick from other answers*

Answer (score 0):

## 05AB1E, 30 bytes

```
TFNT-“ƒŸ€† Tÿ“'µë™ì,}’µëƒŸ!’u,
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##yy9OTMpM/f8/xM0vRPdRw5xjk47ueNS05lHDAoWQw/uBAuqHth5e/ahl0eE1OrWPGmaCeCA1ikB2qc7//wA)

```
TFNT-“ƒŸ€† Tÿ“'µë™ì,}’µëƒŸ!’u,  # full program
 F                              # for N in [0, 1, 2, ...,
T                               # ..., 10...
 F                              # minus 1]...
                   ,            # print...
     “ƒŸ€† Tÿ“                  # "off in Tÿ"...
                                # (implicit) with ÿ replaced by...
  N                             # variable...
    -                           # minus...
   T                            # 10...
                  ì             # prepended with...
              'µë               # "lift"...
                 ™              # in title case...
                   ,            # with trailing newline
                    }           # end loop
                             ,  # print...
                     ’µëƒŸ!’    # "liftoff!"...
                            u   # in uppercase...
                             ,  # with trailing newline
```

Answer (score 0):

## [Deadfish~](https://github.com/TryItOnline/deadfish-), 1402 bytes

```
{{i}ddd}iiiiiic{i}{i}{i}dcdddc{i}iiiicdddddc{d}icc{{d}iii}c{{i}ddd}iiiciiiiic{{d}ii}iic{{i}ddddd}iic{{d}iiiiii}iciiiicdc{{d}iiiiii}iic{{i}dddd}iiiiiic{i}{i}{i}dcdddc{i}iiiicdddddc{d}icc{{d}iii}c{{i}ddd}iiiciiiiic{{d}ii}iic{{i}ddddd}iic{{d}iiiiii}ic{i}iic{{d}iiiii}iiic{{i}dddd}iiiiiic{i}{i}{i}dcdddc{i}iiiicdddddc{d}icc{{d}iii}c{{i}ddd}iiiciiiiic{{d}ii}iic{{i}ddddd}iic{{d}iiiiii}ic{i}ic{{d}iiiiii}ddddddc{{i}dddd}iiiiiic{i}{i}{i}dcdddc{i}iiiicdddddc{d}icc{{d}iii}c{{i}ddd}iiiciiiiic{{d}ii}iic{{i}ddddd}iic{{d}iiiiii}ic{i}c{{d}iiiiii}dddddc{{i}dddd}iiiiiic{i}{i}{i}dcdddc{i}iiiicdddddc{d}icc{{d}iii}c{{i}ddd}iiiciiiiic{{d}ii}iic{{i}ddddd}iic{{d}iiiiii}ic{i}dc{{d}iiiiii}ddddc{{i}dddd}iiiiiic{i}{i}{i}dcdddc{i}iiiicdddddc{d}icc{{d}iii}c{{i}ddd}iiiciiiiic{{d}ii}iic{{i}ddddd}iic{{d}iiiiii}ic{i}ddc{{d}iiiiii}dddc{{i}dddd}iiiiiic{i}{i}{i}dcdddc{i}iiiicdddddc{d}icc{{d}iii}c{{i}ddd}iiiciiiiic{{d}ii}iic{{i}ddddd}iic{{d}iiiiii}ic{i}dddc{{d}iiiiii}ddc{{i}dddd}iiiiiic{i}{i}{i}dcdddc{i}iiiicdddddc{d}icc{{d}iii}c{{i}ddd}iiiciiiiic{{d}ii}iic{{i}ddddd}iic{{d}iiiiii}iciiiiiic{{d}iiiiii}dc{{i}dddd}iiiiiic{i}{i}{i}dcdddc{i}iiiicdddddc{d}icc{{d}iii}c{{i}ddd}iiiciiiiic{{d}ii}iic{{i}ddddd}iic{{d}iiiiii}iciiiiic{{d}iiiiii}c{{i}dddd}iiiiiic{i}{i}{i}dcdddc{i}iiiicdddddc{d}icc{{d}iii}c{{i}ddd}iiiciiiiic{{d}ii}iic{{i}ddddd}iic{{d}iiiiii}iciiiic{{d}iiiiii}ic{{i}dddd}iiiiiicdddcdddc{i}iiiicdddddc{d}icc{{d}iiiiii}iiic
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##xZSxDoAgDES/yI8yPY2dHZt@O0KBWOvgZgkDvd7Rl5CAbcXO57GUIsIKQNkW1apvUFVbaTJgVbURiZhbyUVppK2ldrKedWeihbqT8NBu@38Ywg9JOY3CKxh3Z4C8OHIwEDmSMCJHFkbgSMBgb@0YWRReSmIITxQY2qiP4fO3KeUC)

Answer (score 0):

## [Vyxal](https://github.com/Lyxal/Vyxal) `j`, 32 bytes

```
₀ɾṘƛ«ƛ⟇⋏∨e«¡:£` in T-`+n+;¥⇧\!+J
```

[Try it Online!](http://lyxal.pythonanywhere.com?flags=j&code=%E2%82%80%C9%BE%E1%B9%98%C6%9B%C2%AB%C6%9B%E2%9F%87%E2%8B%8F%E2%88%A8e%C2%AB%C2%A1%3A%C2%A3%60%20in%20T-%60%2Bn%2B%3B%C2%A5%E2%87%A7%5C!%2BJ&inputs=&header=&footer=)