# Golf an HQ9+ transpiler

Tags: code-golf, code-generation, compiler

There was a prior question about [golfing an HQ9+ compiler](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/84170/golf-me-an-hq9-compiler) that translates HQ9+ code into the language it is written in, but that was closed as a duplicate of [the interpreter challenge](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/12956/creating-a-hq9-interpreter) because converting an interpreter to a compiler is seen as trivial. This question is based on the closed one, but has some changes.

Write an [HQ9+](https://esolangs.org/wiki/HQ9%2B) transpiler in a language of your choice. Your submission should be written in some language X, and should take input of HQ9+ source and output a program in another language Y.

The `H` command prints `Hello, world!`.

`Q` outputs the program's code. For this challenge, it must print the transpiled code, not the HQ9+ source, and must not use cheating quine methods. This deviates from the HQ9+ "specification," but is intended to further distinguish this challenge from the interpreter one. For the avoidance of doubt, using `eval`-type functions or methods such as JavaScript's `function.toString()` are *not* considered cheating for the purpose of this challenge.

The `9` command prints the lyrics to "99 Bottles of Beer." You may use any reasonable variant of the lyrics.

In theory, `+` increments the accumulator. However, because the accumulator cannot be addressed, `+` is effectively a no-op.

`H`, `Q`, and `9` may, but are not required to, print trailing newlines. `+` must not produce any output, not even whitespace.

Input must be case-insensitive; `hq`, `hQ`, `Hq`, and `HQ` are the same program. Behavior with unrecognized characters is undefined.

### Rules

1. Language X should satisfy the traditional definition of a language
2. Standard loopholes disallowed
3. Your solution must be testable
4. Y cannot be HQ9+ or an extension of HQ9+
5. Score is calculated as length of transpiler, plus length of output for `H`, plus length of output for `Q`, plus length of output for `9`, plus length of output for `+`, plus length of output for `HQ9+`
6. Submissions compete by language pairs; and HQ9+ to JavaScript transpiler in Python does not compete with an HQ9+ to C transpiler also written in Python.

Comment: Should H, 9, or Q output a trailing newline after their respective commands?

Comment: @ATaco it's up to you.

Comment: "_in another language Y_" Based on the RProgN2 answer, where both X and Y are the same, I assume 'another' can be removed since using the same language is allowed?

Comment: @KevinCruijssen my intention was for them to be different languages, to differentiate this from the closed compiler question, but since there's already an answer with X and Y the same and this doesn't have any close votes, it's okay if they're the same.

Answer (score 6):

## [RProgN 2](https://github.com/TehFlaminTaco/RProgN-2) (outputs RProgN 2), 190 + 17 + 9 + 116 + 1 + 140 = 473 bytes

```
l]`qEL²"«` .x="w?]`9EL²"$99{]]1-'%i J on the wall
%i J!
You take one down, pass it around
%i J on the wall!'`J'bottles of beer'rF}Si`
.y="w?
'[^h9q]'Ør`h"'Hello, world!'p"r
`9'yp'r`q"xp"r` .
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##XY4xCsJAEEX7PcVkUaYwCtptIVaKiJ2VyMpGsprgkkkmK1HEe3gHO4@gB1ujpeV/n8f/XDIdiv4oBKdNNV2@nvL1MDA4j2Uz0Ub9SEepq9bDPnZzWAAV4DMLTeKc@IJIrOkEPjnatrKQUlPEUCZ1DbmHhOlUpOJfjNAscEfeO1sD7WFnLSPPbqvciMHluy1ws81UpfF9Z5NJnFvnKIaG2KURlpKFUXgpkU0lz21sP4cQZKv05Ac)

Uses an ultra simple 99 bottles representation.
Includes newlines between commands, though instances of `p` can be swapped for `w` to remove them at no extra cost. Conditionally includes a the chunk of code for 99 bottles and the quine only if they're needed.

Comment: What language is the output?

Comment: @Somebody RProgN2, I missed the score requirement, so I'll golf this a little more.

Comment: The variant of 99 Bottles of Beer you have is fine, but I've seen a lot of versions without "You," so maybe you could save some bytes by removing that?

Answer (score 5):

## [Retina 0.8.2](https://github.com/m-ender/retina/wiki/The-Language/a950ad7d925ec9316e3e2fb2cf5d49fd15d23e3d) (outputs [Actually](https://github.com/Mego/Seriously/blob/master/docs/commands.txt) or [Seriously](https://github.com/Mego/Seriously/blob/v1/commands.txt)), 14 bytes, score 23

```
T`l9+`LN_
\B
.
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K0otycxL/P8/JCHHUjvBxy@eK8aJS@//fw@uQC5LLm0uj0BLba6MQq6MQC6PQiAPAA) Link includes test cases. Explanation: Port of @KevinCruijssen's 05AB1E answer.

```
T`l9+`LN_
```

Uppercase the input, change `9` to `N`, and delete `+`.

```
\B
.
```

Insert `.`s between pairs of letters. (This also means that the output for `+` is `.`, but it's worth it for the golfiness.)

Comment: It looks like Q is a cheating quine, which is explicitly forbidden?

Answer (score 4):

## [05AB1E](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E/wiki/Commands) (outputs [Actually](https://github.com/Mego/Seriously/blob/master/docs/commands.txt) or [Seriously](https://github.com/Mego/Seriously/blob/v1/commands.txt)), score: 20

<sup>10 [bytes](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E/wiki/Codepage) + 2 for `H` + 2 for `Q` + 2 for `9` - 1 since a trailing `.` is not necessary + 0 for `+` + 5 for `HQ9+`</sup>

```
u9'N:áS'.ý
```

Output language is either [Actually](https://github.com/Mego/Seriously/blob/master/docs/commands.txt) or [Seriously](https://github.com/Mego/Seriously/blob/v1/commands.txt).
It'll output `Hello, World!` and the quine with a single trailing newline, and 99 bottles of beer with two trailing newlines.

[Try it online.](https://tio.run/##yy9OTMpM/f@/1FLdz@rwwmB1vcN7///3KLTUzgAA)

[Try the output for `Hq9+h` in Actually](https://tio.run/##S0wuKU3Myan8/99DL1DPT8/j/38A).
[Try the output for `Hq9+h` in Seriously](https://tio.run/##K04tyswvLc6p/P/fQy9Qz0/P4/9/AA).

**Explanation:**

*05AB1E:*

```python
u            # Uppercase all letters in the (implicit) input-string
 9'N:       '# Replace all 9s with "N"s
     á       # Remove the "+"s by only leaving letters
      S      # Convert the string to a list of characters
       '.ý  '# Join it back together with "." delimiter
             # (after which the result is output implicitly)
```

*Actually / Seriously:*

- `H`: Push "Hello, World!" to the stack
- `N`: Push the entire 99 bottles of beer lyrics (with trailing newline) to the stack
- `Q`: Push the program's source code to the stack
- `.`: Pop and print a string with trailing newline
- Implicitly print the trailing string on the stack which we haven't explicitly printed with a `.`

Comment: It looks like Q is a cheating quine, which is explicitly forbidden?